# Post increment in for loop in java

Tags: java, post-increment

```
int num=0

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    num = num++;
    system.out.println(num);
}
```

I am little confused with the output of above program. It prints five times 0 in output. Why isn't the `num` variable incremented in the loop?

Comment: There is no print statement in your program.

Comment: This program doesn't print anything

Comment: @Renzo,@Amit .. I forgot to add print statement.Now it is there.

Answer (score 1):

`num++` will return the current value of `num` (i.e., 0), and then increment `num`. However, since you re-assign this to `num`, you overwrite the incrementation with the previous value, so `num` remains `0` throughout the program.

Comment: @MouseEvent I thought I did. What would you like elaborated?

Comment: I'd say, show step-by-step what happens to `num`. But maybe the linked duplicate may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment with ++num. For example:

```
int num=0;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    num = ++num;
}

System.out.println(num);
```

Output:

```
5
```

Though you don't need to reassign it every time, `num++` alone would be the proper way to do it.

See previous answer: [Difference between ++var and var++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175316/the-difference-between-var-and-var)

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between `num++` and `++num`. In your case, at first `num` is set to 0. When you say `num = num++;`, it first assgin 0 to `num` (left one), and then apply ++. It really does not matter what the right part of equation does... So that's the reason you've got 5 0's.