# Rock, Paper, Scissors Increment Score not working, can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

My pictures and messages are changing to display win, loss, tie, but my increments in javascript don't seem to be functioning, as my scores don't change. PLEASE HELP :)

```
<body>

    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>

    <button class="rockbtn" id="playRock">Rock</button>
    <button class="play" id="playPaper">Paper</button>
    <button class="play" id="playScissors">Scissors</button>

    <h2 id="humantitle">Human</h2>
    <img alt="humanPlay" id="human" src="img/scissors.png">

    <h2 id="comptitle">Computer</h2>
    <img alt="compPlay" id="computer" src="img/scissors.png">

    <div id="count">
        Human: <input id="playerWin">
        <br><br> Computer: <input id="compWin">
        <br><br> Draw: <input id="draw">
    </div>

    <h3 id="output"></h3>

    <button id="newgame">New Game</button>

    <script src="rps.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

I have my variables established here, which look correct to me...

```
var playerWin = 0;
var compWin = 0;
var draw = 0;
var playerChoice; //Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3

function compChoice() {
    var compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

    if (compChoice === 1) {
        document.getElementById('computer').src = "img/rock.png";
    }

    if (compChoice === 2) {
        document.getElementById('computer').src = "img/paper.png";
    }

    if (compChoice === 3) {
        document.getElementById('computer').src = "img/scissors.png";
    }
```

I have placed my increments in the following if statements according to the game result, but no luck...

```
//draw
        if (playerChoice === compChoice) {
            document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Tied!";

        document.getElementById("draw").innerHTML = draw++;
    }

    //Lose 
    //Rock vs Paper
    else if (playerChoice === 1 && compChoice === 2) {
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Lose! Paper covers rock!"

        document.getElementById("compWin").innerHTML = compWin++;
    }

    //Scissors vs Rock
    else if (playerChoice === 3 && compChoice === 1) {
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Lose! Rock smashes scissors!"

        document.getElementById("compWin").innerHTML = compWin++;
    }

    //Scissors vs Rock
    else if (playerChoice === 2 && compChoice === 3) {
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Lose! Scissors cuts paper!"

        document.getElementById("compWin").innerHTML = compWin++;
    }

    //Win
    //Rock vs Scissors
    else if (playerChoice === 1 && compChoice === 3) {
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Win! Rock smashes scissors!"

        document.getElementById("playerWin").innerHTML = playerWin++;
        }

    //Scissors vs Paper
    else if (playerChoice === 3 && compChoice === 2) {
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Win! Scissors cuts paper!"

        document.getElementById("playerWin").innerHTML = playerWin++;
    }

    //Rock vs Paper
    if (playerChoice === 2 && compChoice === 1) {
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = "You Win! Paper covers rock!"

        document.getElementById("playerWin").innerHTML = playerWin++;
    }
}

//playerChoice = Rock
document.getElementById("playRock").onclick = function () {
    playerChoice = 1;
    document.getElementById('human').src = "img/rock.png";

    compChoice();
}

//playerChoice = Paper
document.getElementById("playPaper").onclick = function () {
    playerChoice = 2;
    document.getElementById('human').src = "img/paper.png";

    compChoice();
}

//playerChoice = Scissors
document.getElementById("playScissors").onclick = function () {
    playerChoice = 3;
    document.getElementById('human').src = "img/scissors.png";

    compChoice();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`++` is a weird opreator. It increments the value *and then returns the original value*.

Just say `draw++;` on a separate line, and then display it on the next line.

Additionally `<input>` elements do not contain HTML. Set the `value` property, not the `innerHTML` property. Or preferably you could just change them to `<span>` elements or something, because they're not inputs.

Comment: `++` increments after the line (or block) for use in `for` loops and the like—that's how I remember it anyway.

Comment: @CD-RUM: It's not necessarily even "the same line or block", it's an expression level thing. It's considered good practice to not mix other operators with `++`/`--` because it gets confusing really fast.

Comment: Had to use <input> as per outline, changed to value property and all is good! Thanks!

Comment: ++var = will increment the value in the current loop. var++ will increment on the next loop. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175339/6444625)

Comment: @hungrykoala: Nope, the timing doesn't have anything to do with loops either. If you have a for loop for example, whether you have var++ or ++var in the increment part makes no difference.