# If there any difference using ++variable instead of variable++ in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c)
>   [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop)

I know that `a++` return the original value of `a` and then add one to `a`, while `++a` increment `a` by one and return `a`. But I can´t see how this is different in a for loop.

Comment: This is getting closed in a matter of minutes. But you are correct that a decent compiler would make this a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

well if you are operation on an array in the for loop that is zero indexed and you use x++ then the first value to be processed will be the 0 index value however if you use ++x then the value to be processed first will be the 1 index.

In simpler terms:

x++ increments the value of variable x after processing the current statement.

++x increments the value of variable x before processing the current statement.

Comment: No.  The question was asked in the context of a for loop.