# Multiple increment/decrements in a single statement

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 0;
(++a)+(a++)+(++a); 
print(a);
```

This prints 3. I'm assuming it only executes single increment.

```
var a = 0;
(++a)+(a++)+(--a);
```

This prints 1. What's the rule to follow here?

Thank you.

Comment: Here. read the difference between i++ and ++i http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop

Comment: I'm sure you're just curious (I am, for the answer), but is there a reason you're doing this? I mean, why can't you increment the number as you want *before* you add them up?

Comment: Yes, it's mainly curiosity. I am also developing a scripting DSL. That's why i would like to know how a common language like javascript implements these.

Comment: Don't write code like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*JavaScript* is executed left-to-right. You can see this by seeing what happens when you use multiplication

```
a = 1;
   ++a *   a; // 4
//   2 *   2  =  4

a = 1;
     a * ++a; // 2
//   1 *   2  =  2

a = 1;
   a++ * a  ; // 2
// 1   * 2    =  2

a = 1;
   a   * a++; // 1
// 1   * 1    =  1
```

After each of these, the resulting `a` is `2`.

Comment: Thank you. Then b = (++a)+(a++)+(++a); is b = 1 + 1 + 3. 
b is 5, a is 3.
Looking at the statement i would think it is 6. Like this:
a+=1; a+=1; b=a+a+a; a+=1;
I gotta learn to think like javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You're not assigning the outcome of your addition to anything.  You do this:

```
(++a)+(a++)+(++a);
```

Which increments `a` 3 times.   `0 + 3 = 3`  so `a` is the value 3.

Comment: Haha I can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: @mikbal In this case it is completely irrelevant.  You don't do anything with the outcome.

Comment: @mikbal Yeah, it would be different if you stored it in `var b` and printed the value of `b` (it would be 5)