# java complex statement execution order

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(info + ": " + ++x);
```

is this statement equivalent to

```
x++;
System.out.println(info + ": " + x);
```

and

```
System.out.println(info + ": " + x++);
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(info + ": " + x);
x++;
```

As JVM can only process one statement at a time, does it divides these statements like this?

Comment: I came here expecting some crazy threading madness.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of ... well, hundreds of other questions ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop and others)

Answer (score 3):

Yes and yes.

`++x` will be executed before the containing statement, ie the value of `x` will be incremented before it's used.

`x++` will be executed after the containing statement, ie the value will be used and then the variable `x` incremented.

To be clear: in both cases the value of variable `x` will be changed.

Comment: I am asking while executing that statement how will jvm will divide it?

Comment: This answer is not correct. x++ will be post-incremented after the value is obtained.

Comment: @EJP that's what I said above