# Algorithm for sorting an array with 4 options

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I was given a task to sort an array that is filled with (non negative) integers.

They should be sorted such that the output is in the following order:

- Numbers where the remainder of them divided by 4 is 0
- Numbers where the remainder of them divided by 4 is 1
- Numbers where the remainder of them divided by 4 is 2
- Numbers where the remainder of them divided by 4 is 3

I tried to write a simple algorithm that should work at O(n) (the task is to write the code efficiently).

But I think it's a mess, a few cases didn't work (for example when I tried an array where the first few numbers have remainders of 3).

Any suggestion on how to fix it or a better way of doing this?

```
public static void sortByFour(int[] arr)
{
    int zeroR = -1, oneR = 0, twoR = arr.length-1, threeR = arr.length;

    do
    {
        if (arr[oneR]%4==1)
         oneR++;
        else if (arr[oneR]%4==0)
        {
            zeroR++;
            int temp = arr[oneR];
            arr[oneR] = arr[zeroR];
            arr[zeroR] = temp;
            oneR++;
        }
        else if (arr[oneR]%4==2)
        {
            twoR--;
            int temp = arr[oneR];
            arr[oneR] = arr[twoR];
            arr[twoR] = temp;
        }
        else if (arr[oneR]%4==3)
        {
            threeR--;
            int temp = arr[oneR];
            arr[oneR] = arr[threeR];
            arr[threeR] = temp;
        }
    } while (oneR < threeR && oneR < twoR);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) can do the trick for you. Note that you can overcome the `O(n)` extra space factor of bucket sort by looping 4 times (once per each reminder), something like (java-like pseudo code):

```
final int REMINDER = 4; //4 because you use %4
int curr = -1;
for (int r = 0; r < REMINDER ; r++) { 
   for (int i = curr + 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
       if (arr[i] % REMINDER  == r) { 
          //swap elements:
          int temp = arr[i];;
          arr[i] = arr[++curr];
          arr[curr] = temp;
       }
   }
}
```

The  idea is to 'remember' where you have last set element, and iterate the array 4 times, and swap elements with matching reminder to the desired location (which you remembered).

Complexity is still `O(n)` with `O(1)` extra space.

An alternative is `O(n)` (but much better constants) time with `O(n)` space is to use a classic bucket sort, with a single pass store all elements in 4 different lists according to the desired reminder, and in a 2nd pass - on those 4 lists, fill the original array with the elements according to the desired order.

Comment: Nice idea. The only disadvantage of the in-place method is that it isn't stable, while bucket sort is stable.

Comment: It's "remainder", not "reminder" (corrected in question), but "divisor" seems like a more appropriate variable name for your code (otherwise I would've edited it myself).

Comment: sorry for the beginner question but why this doesn't work with "curr++"? nevermind got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop