# Iterate over std::multimap and delete certain entries

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I want to iterate over all items in a `std::multimap` (all values of all keys), and delete all entries that satisfy some condition:

```
#include <map>

typedef int KEY_TYPE;
typedef int VAL_TYPE;

bool shouldRemove(const KEY_TYPE&, const VAL_TYPE&);

void removeFromMap(std::multimap<KEY_TYPE,VAL_TYPE>& map){
    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++){
        if (shouldRemove(it->first,it->second))
            map.erase(it);
    }
}
```

The iteration works unless the first item gets deleted, and the following error is thrown then:

> map/set iterator not incrementable

How can the `removeFromMap` function be rewritten in order to work properly? The code should work for all kinds of key- and value types of the map.

I am using C++ 11 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Normally one use the return value of map.erase(iterator), since it returns the iterator to the next element or end, if it was the last element

Comment: @Erbureth You should add that as an answer :-)

Comment: @KarlNicoll However after digging more deeply, the Erase-remove idiom is not applicable on `std::set`, `std::map` and friends, because their value type is not `MoveAssignable`. And I have no idea how to implement it on such containers anyway, as it works by shifting elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increment your iterator *before* you do the erase. When you do `map.erase(it);` the iterator `it` becomes invalid. However, other iterators in the map will still be valid. Therefore you can fix this by doing a post-increment on the iterator...

```
auto it = map.begin();
const auto end = map.end();

while (it != end)
{
    if (shouldRemove(it->first,it->second))
    {
        map.erase(it++);
                 // ^^ Note the increment here.
    }
    else
    {
       ++it;
    }
}
```

The post-increment applied to `it` inside the `map.erase()` parameters will ensure that `it` remains valid after the item is erased by incrementing the iterator to point to the next item in the map just before erasing.

```
map.erase(it++);
```

... is functionally equivalent to...

```
auto toEraseIterator = it;    // Remember the iterator to the item we want to erase.
++it;                         // Move to the next item in the map.
map.erase(toEraseIterator);   // Erase the item.
```

As @imbtfab points out in the comments, you can also use `it = map.erase(it)` to do the same thing in C++11 without the need for post-incrementing.

Note also that the `for` loop has now been changed to a while loop since we're controlling the iterator manually.

Additionally, if you're looking to make your `removeFromMap` function as generic as possible, you should consider using template parameters and pass your iterators in directly, rather than passing in a reference to the multi-map. This will allow you to use any map-style container type, rather than forcing a `multimap` to be pased in.

e.g.

```
template <typename Iterator>
void removeFromMap(Iterator it, const Iterator &end){
    ...
}
```

This is how the standard C++ `<algorithm>` functions do it also (e.g. [`std::sort(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)).

Comment: that works for me, thanks! However, I do not understand why using the post-increment way fixes the problem - why do `erase(it); it++;` and `erase(it++);` differ?

Comment: When you do `erase(it)`, the variable `it` is no longer usable. Trying to increment `it` after it has been erased is *undefined behaviour*. By doing `erase(it++)`, you increment `it` *before* erase is called, but still pass the old un-incremented iterator into the `erase` function. It is equivalent to the following: `auto newIt = std::next(it); map.erase(it); it = newIt;`. You might get a better understanding by [seeing how the post-increment operator works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop).

Comment: @Karl: In your comment, you want `auto newIt = std::next(it)` (or something else.  What you have is incrementing it as well as assigning the incremented value to newIt.

Comment: Since this is C++11, avoid the confusion, just use `it = map.erase(it);`

Comment: @imbtfab - You should add that as another answer, rather than letting me take all the credit for it :-)

Comment: Help yourself, there's enough answers here already...and I'd just be copying most of yours anyway ;)