# Prefix and postfix increment in for loop

Tags: c#, post-increment, pre-increment

Given the following code

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i) {
    if (i==j) {
        Console.WriteLine ("equal");
    }
    j++;
}
```

I expected that `++i` would change `i` from initial `0` to `1` and thus `i==j` evaluated to `false`.

But it did not. Why?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop

Comment: Before loop goes to `++i` and `i` and `j` are equal.

Comment: This is not a question about `i++` vs `++i` but about how a for-loop works. @qaphla has your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a loop in the form `for (a; b; c) { d; }`, you can treat this as the following `while` loop:

```
a;
while(b) {
    d;
    c;
}
```

As you can see, the increment doesn't occur until after the first iteration, regardless of whether it's a pre- or post- increment.

Comment: is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Ask: It is just a trivial consequence of how [`for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) is defined and it’s a language-agnostic fact. You can read it e.g. in [*Looping* section of *Chapter 4: Flow Control* in *Beginning Visual C# 2010*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/hh147286%28VS.88%29.aspx#Looping).

Answer (score 3):

`++i` (or anything in the 3rd segment) will not be evaluated until after the first iteration.

No matter what though, even if it evaluated before your `if`, it would still not work the way you thought it did.

Doing `i++` or `++i` won't change anything because it would have been evaluated prior to it being used.

The true difference comes when you use it like so:

```
int i = 0;
if (i++ == 0) { /* True because the old value of "i" was used to compare */ }

i = 0;
if (++i == 0) { /* Not true because "i" got changed to 1 before the compare. */ }
```

Comment: *"i" got changed to 1 after it compared* is not quite accurate. `i` changes, but `i++` evaluates to its old value, which is then compared

Comment: @TimS. True. I'll reword.

Answer (score 2):

- `i++` increments and evaluates to (i.e. results in, similar to `return`ing) `i`'s **old** value
- `++i` increments and evaluates to `i`'s **new** value

The statements `i++;` and `++i;` are the same because you don't use the result, so the only important part is that they both increment `i`. Used in a `for` loop how you are, you're using them as standalone statements, you aren't using the values of the expressions `i++`/`++i`.

Answer (score 0):

The compare is evaluated before the increment.  Prefix or postfix makes no difference.