# C# Recursive Increment Decrement not working as parameters

Tags: c#, recursion, increment

I am using recursion to add two numbers together, By adding 1 to the first input one at a time until I have reached the value of the second.
Why does this work...

```
        private static int AddMethod(int input1, int input2)
    {
        if (input2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input1);
            return (input1);
        }
        else
        {
            input1++;
            input2--;
            return AddMethod(input1, input2);
        }

    }
```

But not this..

```
    private static int AddMethod(int input1, int input2)
    {
        if (input2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input1);
            return (input1);
        }
        else
        {
            return AddMethod(input1++, input2--);
        }

    }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4.0

Comment: What doesnt work about it? it looks more like you want `return AddMethod(++input1, --input2);`

Comment: There's a good explanation of what is going on at [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729).

Comment: Useful [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `return AddMethod(input1++, input2--);` first passes your inputs, and THEN increments and decrements.

Try
`return AddMethod(++input1, --input2);`

Answer (score 2):

Post fix increment works by first "assigning" the value, then incrementing the value.

Compare:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;

int x = a++;
int y = ++b;
```

So in your case, the value you pass to `AddMethod` is the unchanged value, it modifies the value of `input1` and `input2` after they are passed.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `++` and `--` operators are executed after passing the values as parameters to the function.

Your code:

```
return AddMethod(input1++, input2--);
```

Is equal to:

```
int result AddMethod(input1, input2);
input1++;
input2--;
return result;
```

Instead of all this, you could use:

```
return AddMethod(++input1, --input2);
```