# Javascript: Why does prefix operator work with modulus but not postfix operator?

Tags: javascript, modulus, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I am trying to make a function that increments until it reaches 3 and then starts back from zero (so, called three times it would log `0` then `1` then `2`. When using the `%` operator with the pre and post fix operators, I have confusing results.

Here are my two functions:

```
var i, j = 0, 0
function run () { 
  console.log(i); 
  i = i++ % 3;
 } // Called three times logs 0, 0, 0
```

And

```
function newRun () {
  console.log(j);
  j = ++j % 3;
} // Called three times it logs 0, 1, 2
```

Why does the prefix operator work and the postfix does not (i.e. in the first function why is `i` never incremented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the modulo operator. Even

```
i = i++;
```

doesn't work - it takes a value, increments it, and then overwrites it with the initially taken value. See also [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484462/1048572) for how they work.

You probably want to write

```
i = (i + 1) % 3;
```

Comment: Right. So, if the the initial value is incremented and then overwritten, wouldn't it be overwritten to `1` then '2' etc?

Comment: ahh, I see. Your link cleared it up - the old value is always returned so it is continually overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

when working with pre- and postfix operators, it's often good to write down the code which is actually executed.

```
i ++
```

means:

```
tmp1 = i
i = i + 1
```

(`tmp1` is the result of the whole operation).
while

```
++ i
```

means

```
i = i + 1
tmp1 = i
```

That means

```
i = i ++ % 3
```

is actually

```
tmp1 = i
i = i + 1
i = tmp1 % 3
```

As you can see, the second line as never an effect because the last line overwrites it.

Comment: A little lost on your second and and fourth examples here. is `tmp1 = i` wrong here because it assigns the value of `i` to `tmp1` (not a reference?)

Comment: A number is a value type, i.e. it never changes its value. `i=1` means: Create an instance of type number and put `1` into it and assign the reference to the alias `i`. So `tmp1 = i` copies the reference and `i = i + 1` creates a new instance with the value `i + 1` and assigns this again to `i`. That way, the value of `tmp1` doesn't change.