# Using Java decrement operator in a recursive function

Tags: java, function, recursion, variable-assignment

Here is a recursive function -

```
private void printVar01(int t){
    if(t != 0){
        logp.info("o: " + t);
        printVar01(t-1);
    }
}
```

The same function with a slight modification -

```
private void printVar02(int t){
    if(t != 0){
        logp.info("o: " + t);
        printVar02(t--);
    }
}
```

If I pass in a integer value, like 4, printVar01 works as expected, where *t* decrements to 0 in successive recursive calls, eventually causing the program to exit.

With printVar02, *t* stays at value 4.

Why? I am assuming this has something to do with variable assignment and/or how values are passed to functions.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: yup i should've read that doc twice :). also this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use --t instead of t--:

```
private static void printVar02(int t){
if(t != 0){
    logp.info("o: " + t);
    printVar02(--t);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is right if method name is `printVar` and not `printVar02`.

Comment: that what he meant, i got that when he said "Here is a recursive funtion"
i'm sure he was just testing it that why he used 01 and 02

Comment: ***Why*** should you use --t instead of t--? What is the explanation? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30135687/edit), not here in comments (****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

`t-1` does not change `t` while `t--` does.

- `t-1` gives you a new value without affecting the actual value of `t`
- `t--` gives you `t` and then decreases the value of `t`

I think `printVar02` should work fine and in `printVar01` the value remains the same.

---

For the comment of [`DoubleMa`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4880309/doublema)

> actually 01 will works not 02, in 01 t is changing, but in 02 the
> function is calling itself before changing the value of T, he just
> need to use --t;

*I also definitely suspect the recursive call.*

If you mean `printVar` = `printVar01` = `printVar02`.

If you are calling `printVar` recursively then `t-1` will work as a recursive call. It will make it work and in `t--` it will pass the same value, `4`, every time as it's a postdecrement. Use predecrement, `--t`, instead.

Comment: actually 01 will works not 02, in 01 t is changing, but in 02 the function is calling itself before changing the value of T, he just need to use --t;

Answer (score 2):

Post decrement decreases the value by 1 after execution of the statement `printVar(t--)`. Hence each time 4 is being passed to the function.

You should use --t instead which does the decrement first.