# c++ iterator stuck at first value

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and I've run into some behaviour that I can't explain. The two pieces of code below provide different results, while I would expect them to be equivalent:

```
success = true;
vector<instruction>::const_iterator i;
for (i = instructions.begin(); i != instructions.end(); ++i) {
    bool up = update(*i);
    success = success && up;        
}
```

and

```
success = true;
vector<instruction>::const_iterator i;
for (i = instructions.begin(); i != instructions.end(); ++i) {
    success = success && update(*i);        
}
```

I have the impression that the second version always takes the initial value of the iterator. Could someone explain me the reason?

Comment: Short circuiting

Comment: We do not know what `update` returns, so `success` may or may not be `true`.

Comment: Also note you are pre-incrementing `++i` in the first example and post-incrementing `i++` in the second. It shouldn't make a difference, but just be aware. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop) for more detail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two pieces of code are *not* equivalent.

The first one always calls `update`, while the second one will not.  The reason is that `&&` does something called `short-circuit boolean evaluation`.  If  `success` is false, the second half of the expression is not evaluated.

Note that you did not post what `update` is or what is returned.  Therefore we can only assume what may be able to be returned from `update`, which is either going to be `true` or `false`.

If you wanted `update` to always be called, it should be placed first in the `&&` expression.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that, while `success` is always `true` on the first iteration, it may not be after that, depending on the result of the first call to `update(*i);`

Comment: Perhaps also worth commenting that a fix is to write `success = update(*i) && success;` .. and the whole thing becomes easier if you write `success=true; for (const auto& inst : instructions) success = update(inst) && success;`  (On multiple lines of course)

Comment: thanks that was the reason indeed! Strange thing is that I knew that, but I had neglected that my program actually requires that `update` be called all the time. So for the purpose of knowing the value of `success` the two formulations are equivalent, but still the outcomes of the program are very different. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The operator `&&` will not evaluate the right hand side if the result is computable with just the left hand side value. We call this *short-circuiting*.

Once `success` is `false`, `update(*i)` will no longer be called.

Aside from your first block of code (which always calls `update(*i)`), one fix is to use the operator `&` instead which always evaluates both arguments. Another fix is to write

`success = update(*i) && success;`

But that's vulnerable to recalcitrant refactoring. Better still, use

`success &= update(*i);`

But be aware of this comment by @Angew:

Using `&=` in a boolean context is dangerous. What if `update` now (or after a future refactoring) returns an `int` with the semantics "non-zero for true" (cf. [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and friends)? Remember that `bool(true & 2)` is `false`.

Comment: @Angew: You raise an important point and I would agree with you in C, but in C++ we have the luxury of a "proper" Boolean type, and relational operators returning true and false, as opposed to 1 and 0.

Comment: Given that computing wisdom only emanates from bug-fixing, and so therefore you're wiser than me in this respect, I've copied your caution to the answer.