# c++ for loop post-increment pre-increment difference

Tags: c++, for-loop

i've been searching for an answer, but i get more and more confused.

i have these 2 for loops

```
for (int i = 1; (i < 5) && move.from[i - 1]; i++) {
    int const departurePoint = move.from[i - 1];
    int arrivalPoint = move.to[i - 1];

    if (arrivalPoint < 0) { // A blot was hit
        arrivalPoint = -arrivalPoint;
        board[1 - turn][BAR - arrivalPoint]--; // Remove the blot
        board[1 - turn][BAR]++; // and place it on the bar */
    }

    board[turn][departurePoint]--; // Move our own checker
    board[turn][arrivalPoint]++; // to it's landing spot.
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 1; (i < 5) && move.from[i - 1]; ++i) {
    int const departurePoint = move.from[i - 1];
    int arrivalPoint = move.to[i - 1];

    if (arrivalPoint < 0) { // We hit a blot
        arrivalPoint = -arrivalPoint;
        board[1 - turn][BAR - arrivalPoint]++; // Replace the blot
        board[1 - turn][BAR]--; // remove it from the bar
    }

    board[turn][departurePoint]++; // Replace our own checker
    board[turn][arrivalPoint]--; // to it's original spot.
}
```

my questions are:

1. In the for loop statement with pre-increment, has i been incremented when the "move.from[i - 1] is evaluated?
2. Has i been incremented in the body of the statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 1; (i < 5) && move.from[i - 1]; i++ /*i increments here and nowhere else*/)
```

and

```
for (int i = 1; (i < 5) && move.from[i - 1]; ++i /*i increments here and nowhere else*/)
```

Both codes are equivalent. The difference is very slight and it does not apply to this example.

when `i==3`,

`++i` means:
`4=i+1=(++i)` then `i=4`.

`i++` means:
`3= i =(i++)` then `i=4`.

it does not make a difference until you assign it to another variable:

```
for(...; ...; k=i++)
```

or

```
for(...; ...; k=++i)
```

---

`i+1` means:

store `i` to a temporary variable. Increase the temporary variable by one. It reads `i` but does not write to `i`. `i` will change only on `++`, `--` or `i=` and a few other cases.

Comment: Okay. Wouldn't this be the same then? for (int i = 0; (i < 4) && move.from[i]; ++i) {
  int const departurePoint = move.from[i];...

Comment: @helgovic, No. In your case, `++i` and `i++` are identical. The result of increment is not used. The condition `(i < 5)` is checked after the increment. Therefore, it does not care about the `i++` or `++i`.

Answer (score 2):

Your short question is ***What is the difference between `i++` and `++i` is the value of the expression?***

The value **`i++` is the value of `i` before the increment**. The value of **`++i` is the value of `i` after the increment**.

**Example:**

```
int i = 2;
std::cout << i++ << std::cout; // shows 2
std::cout << i << std::cout; // shows 3

i = 2;
std::cout << ++i << std::cout; // shows 3
std::cout << i << std::cout; // shows 3
```

The `i--` and `--i` operators works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop takes two statements and an expresion like this:

```
for(init_statement;condition_expresion;progress_statement){
 //...body...
}
```

The semantic of this instruction is basically the same as writing:

```
init_statement;
while(condition_expresion){
  //...body...
  progress_statement;
}
```

Notice the side effect of both `i++` and `++i` is the same, the variable `i` is incremented by one. Those two instructions are different when they are used as expresions, `i++` evaluates to the value of `i` before the increment, and `++i` evaluates to the value after the increment. This is all irrelevant for the for loop, as the value of the progression statement is discarded.