# Mean and Mode of vector array - How can I make a smaller improvement in the function

Tags: c++, performance, function, c++11, stdvector

Doing an exercise to find the `mean` and `mode` of a list of numbers input by a user. I have written the program and it works, but I'm wondering if my function 'calcMode' is too large for this program. I've just started looking into functions which is a first attempt. Would it be better to write smaller functions? and if so what parts can I split? Im pretty new to C++ and also looking if I can improve this code. Is there any changes I can make to make this run more efficient?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int calcMean(vector<int> numberList) 
{

    int originNumber = numberList[0];
    int nextNumber;
    int count = 0;
    int highestCount = 0;
    int mean = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numberList.size() - 1; i++) 
    {
            nextNumber = numberList[i];
            if (nextNumber == originNumber) 
                count++;
            else 
            {
                cout << "The Number " << originNumber << " appears " << count << " times." << endl;
                count = 1;
                originNumber = nextNumber;
            }
        }

    if (count > highestCount)
    {
        highestCount = count;
        mean = originNumber;
    }
    cout << "The Number " << originNumber << " appears " << count << " times." << endl;     
    return mean;
}

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v;
    int userNumber;
    cout << "Please type a list of numbers so we can arrange them and find the mean: "<<endl;

    while (cin >> userNumber)  v.push_back(userNumber);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (int x : v)    cout << x << " | ";

    cout << endl;
    cout<<calcMean(v)<<" is the mean"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ConstantFurstenberg Regarding code-review , you can use the same id and password to login https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and there you can post your WORKING CODE. If someone answer your question anywhere in stack-exchange  websites, you can do as mentioned follows:
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to watch out for is copying vectors when you don't need to.

The function signature

```
int calcMode(vector<int> numberList)
```

means the `numberList` will get copied.

```
int calcMode(const & vector<int> numberList)
```

will avoid the copy. Scott Meyer's Effective C++ talks about this.

As an aside, calling is a `numberList` is misleading - it isn't a `list`.

There are a couple of points that are worth being aware of in the for loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numberList.size()-1; i++)
```

First, this might calculate the `size()` every time. An optimiser might get rid of this for you, but some people will write

```
for (unsigned int i = 0, size=numberList.size(); i <= size-1; i++)
```

The `size` is found once this way, instead of potentially each time.
They might even change the `i++` to `++i`. There used to a potential overhead here, since the post-increment might involve an extra [temporary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop)

One question - are you *sure this gives the right answer?
The comparison `nextNumber == originNumber` is looking at the first number to begin with. 
Try it with 1, 2, 2.

One final point. If this is general purpose, what happens if the list is empty?

Comment: Legend thanks for the detailed response. So I moved my mean if statement one bracket lower and now it works fine (took it out of the else check). I start the value of count at 0 to begin with so thats why I evaluate nextNumber == originNumber. But every check after that count starts at 1. And I will have to put a check in to see if its empty xD. Ill also keep in mind the handy tips to stop unnecessary size() checks and not creating a vector copy. Ive update the code to now work with 1 2 2 etc =]

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be better to write smaller functions?

- Yes, you can make do the same job using `std::map<>;` which could be
  a much appropriate way to count the repetition of the array elements.
- Secondly, it would be much safer to know, what is the size of the
  array. Therefore I suggest the following:

`std::cout << "Enter the size of the array: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> arraySize;`

- In the `calcMode()`, you can easily const reference, so that array
  will not be copied to the function.

Here is the updated code with above mentioned manner which you can refer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int calcMode(const std::map<int,int>& Map)
{
    int currentRepetition = 0;
    int mode = 0;

    for(const auto& number: Map)
    {
        std::cout << "The Number " << number.first << " appears " << number.second << " times." << std::endl;

        if(currentRepetition < number.second )
        {
            mode = number.first;  // the number
            currentRepetition = number.second; // the repetition of the that number
        }
    }
    return mode;
}

int main()
{
    int arraySize;
    int userNumber;
    std::map<int,int> Map;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of the array: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> arraySize;

    std::cout << "Please type a list of numbers so we can arrange them and find the mean: " << std::endl;
    while (arraySize--)
    {
        std::cin >> userNumber;
        Map[userNumber]++;
    }

    std::cout << calcMode(Map)<<" is the mode" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**  After posting this answer, I have found that you have edited your function with `mean` instead of `mode`. I really didn't get it.

**Regarding mean & mode:** I recommend you to read more. Because in general, a data set can have multiple modes and only one mean.

Comment: hey @JeJo yea sorry I updated it from mean to mode about 2 hours ago. Sorry for the inconvenience. The code I have written is to find the mode (number appearing the most). Like I mentioned im very new to C++. This was purely a basic program to determine 1 Mode. Id have to do some reading as you suggested if I was looking at more modes.

Comment: Also I was goign to ask why it matters what size the array is? And why do people show the std::? it makes readability so much harder (for myself anyway)

Comment: How would you stop reading userNumber from the console in your program? that is the question. There are many other ways, but what I have shown here is a simple one. And for second question; praticing with std::, I would recommend to read this, which is a well explained answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I just pressed ctrl z to exit. Would it be better to put a condition in to say if 'q' is entered or '0' to avoid a new variable, then to quit reading user Input? Also thanks for that I had a read and I'll start to use th std:: as good practice:)

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't split this code up in smaller blocks, only if i'd want to reuse some code in other methods. But just for this method it's more readable like this.

The order of excecution is aroun O(n) for calc which is quite oke if you ask me

Comment: hey Stan thanks for the feedback. Is there somewhere I can go to learn how to calculate execution time the O(n) you've mentioned?

Comment: phew, I've learned it in my classes. I don't know a place where you can learn about it, but I'm sure Youtube has some nice videos about it. It's actually just some basic maths :)