# Noob explanation of ++x

Tags: c#

Please explain ++x in layman's terms

I tried searching for this here, youtube, Google, Chegg, and a programming community on discord. I'm pretty desperate now because I I still don't understand this. haha
I know that it's a prefix which means that it increments the value then does the expression, but I don't exactly understand what that means. 
I also know what y -= 3 means which is y-3.

```
int x = 8;
int y = ++x;
 if (x > 5)
 y -= 3;
 else
 y = 9;
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

I don't know what the answer is.

Comment: You can run this code to see the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop works as well.

Comment: The duplicate is for Java, **but works for all languages**

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+-%3D+mean+c%23

Comment: A better duplicate for this (since the selected duplicate is imprecise at best and misleading at worst) might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/34092 .

Answer (score -2):

```
int x = 10;
int y = ++x;
```

now y == 11 and x == 11

```
int x = 10;
int y = x++;
```

now y==10 and x == 11

In both cases `x` is increased by 1. The difference is that when you use `++x` it returns the value after increment (increment first and assign second) while `x++` returns the value before increment (assign first and increment second).