# What is better style: ++x or x++ in for loops

Tags: c++

I was having a discussion with a stubborn person I know over which of these two forms was more semantically correct, although there is no logical difference to the code:

1.

```cpp
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
// do something
```

2.

```cpp
for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
// do something
```

Is it better to pre-increment or post-increment in a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop)

Comment: (2) but when compiled should make no difference.

Comment: No @FloriBruci that one simply explains the process without commenting on the style of the two alternatives.

Comment: This is a very opinion-based question but generally speaking no one cares when it comes to simple integers and Microsoft uses `++it` in their implementation of the standard library whenever the thing getting incremented is an iterator. Make of that what you will.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, prefer `++it` over `it++` unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the side effect of post increment, then the pre increment version is the better choice.

In case of an `int` it does not result in different code, but in case of an iterator you probably get better performance with pre increment because post increment needs to create a temporary copy of the original iterator. You can easily see that when comparing pre increment

```
class T {
    T& operator++() {
        this-> .... // do the increment
        return *this;
    }
}
```

with the post increment

```
class T {
    T operator++(int) {
        const T old{ *this };
        this-> .... // do the increment
        return old;
    }
}
```

If the iterator is just a pointer then the compiler might be able to optimize so much that you don't see a difference, but if the iterator is more complex, then you will see a difference.

Of course the same applies to prefix and postfix decrement.

Comment: This depends on the underlying processor architecture and cannot be generalized.

Comment: `but in case of an iterator you probably get better performance with post increment because pre increment needs to create a temporary copy of the original iterator.` Quite the opposite. It is the post increment which necessitates the copy. That said, it too can be optimised away.

Comment: I would say, you expect copying to optimize away. Iterators are designed to be passed by value, so iterators copying is lightweight operation prone to optimization. So actually there's no difference for iterators either.

Comment: @eerorika Of course, you are right. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If a modern compiler with optimisations switched on produces different code for `x++` and `++x` for this particular case then you ought to switch compiler vendors.

I always write `++x` since (i) the type of `x` might change to a non-POD in the future and `x++` could take an expensive copy in such a case, (ii) because it buries a message in your code that you think about things like this, and (iii) because I'm old fashioned.

(I insist on `++x` in my company.)

Comment: I agree with all the other points, but how is `++x` old fashioned?

Comment: @Ayxan: Some early C compilers didn't optimise ++x for even an `int`. In this respect COBOL and FORTRAN were ahead of their time.

Comment: You mean they didn't optimize `x++`?

Comment: @Ayxan: In the early days of C you had to hold the compiler's hand much more tightly than you do now. These days you almost need to get out of this habit and trust the compiler to make optimisations itself.

Answer (score 1):

Does not matter.

Might matter for iterators instead of `int`s, but actually does not matter to them either.

I'd yield to a stubborn person.

Or retreat by saying "`i += 1`" (but that may be worse for iterators)

Comment: I know it doesn't matter but I was wondering which solution was more idiomatic.

Comment: @EtherealUnagi Neither. Both are equally idiomatic. Pre-increment is simpler to understand, so that is usually used.

Answer (score 0):

```
// pre-fix operator
MyCustomClass& operator++()
{
    return *this;
}

// post-fix operator
MyCustomClass operator++(int)
{
  MyCustomClass tmp(*this);
  operator++();
  return tmp;
}
```

and as a best practice:

to be consistent with the built in operators, your built in postfix operator
should return the old value, thar value is returned as a value and never as a reference
but for prefix operators you should return a reference to the modified object.

Comment: You prefix operator is a no-op.