# Can the update statement in for loop work with both postfix with prefix? (i++ and ++i)

Tags: c, for-loop

For example

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d \n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can the `++i` in the for loop updation be `i++`?

Comment: Maybe. If you tried it, and it didn't work, can you ask about that?

Comment: The question is unclear to me, please specify why "Yes." (after a quick experiment of your own) is not the answer.

Comment: Indeed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop

Comment: Postfix or prefix only matters if you mix them with other operators in the same expression. Which is, as it turns out, very bad and dangerous practice. So generally you don't need worry about postfix vs prefix: if you find a use for one over the other, it just means that your code is ugly and dangerous.

Comment: (And yes `*a++ = *b++` is a common way to implement certain copy functions, but it was never well-written C.)

Comment: @Lundin what why where?! K&R most certainly uses `while ((s[i++] = t[j++]) != '\0') /* copy t */;`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala And the Tyrannosaurus was most likely a scavenger. So what?

Comment: So you're saying that K&R didn't know how to write C well. Ok :D Back in the days with single-pass compilers it *was* well-written C.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the ++i in the for loop updation can be i++?

Answer is **Yes**

You can check the o/p in both the case. It print the same value.