# Why there is no difference in number of times loop run when using ++i vs i++?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {

 }
```

vs

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
 {

 }
```

Both these loop run n times but we know that ++i and i++ are different.
So can anyone explain what is happening in backend in gcc compiler using cpp?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think `i++` and `++i` are different in the loop you've shown?

Comment: `++i` and `i++` are different, but the value of `i` in `i<n` is same in both cases. The value of the increment expression is not relevant for the loop

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295300/4342498) on the dupe might be the most helpful for you.

Comment: You may be thinking of `while (++i<n)` vs `while (i++<n)`. This is not the same thing. `i<n` checks the value of `i` after the incrementation happens. Whether you do `++i` or `i++` the value of `i` is the same. It is incremented by 1. The only difference between `++i` and `i++` is the value is evaluates to, but this value is never used in a `for` loop.