# C - While loops once extra after checking condition?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am trying to figure out the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEN 10
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    
    while (n++ < TEN)
        printf("%5d", n);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints 1 through 10. Isn't it supposed to print 1 to 9 only, since `n++` will make it 10, and the condition while (10 < TEN) would fail hence should exit before printing?

When I change it to `while (++n < TEN)` I get 1 to 9, which makes sense because the addition is made before the check.

My so far understanding is that the `n++` will add after the condition has been checked, hence it will print 10 (since `++n` checks before, and `n++` check after). Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on pre-increment and post-increment operators.

Comment: The value evaluated in the `if` statement for `++n` is `n + 1`, for `n++` it is `n`.

Comment: It prints 1 greater than the value that was tested (because it was incremented after testing).

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec

Comment: [Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop) may be helpful. It asks about a `for` loop which is a little different but there is discussion about the difference between pre and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `n++` ([postfix increment operator](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2)), the value of `n` gets incremented **after** the `while` statement, therefore the while condition `n++ < TEN` is first verified, and only after the value of `n` is updated.

When the last iteration of your while instruction `while (n++ < TEN)` is executed, `n` is still 9 (and gets incremented by 1 right after) that's why it prints 10 as the last value:

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```