# java for loop pre-increment vs post-increment

Tags: java, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t changing the pre to the post increment at the iteration part of a for loop make a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-for)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
   System.out.print(i + ".."); //prints 0..1..2


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   System.out.print(i + ".."); //prints 0..1..2
```

So what is the difference? in what cases can the pre-increment be used wrongly or by mistake which causes a bug...