# why does i++ and ++i in a for loop behave the same?

Tags: java, loops, increment

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop)
>   [java for loop pre-increment vs post-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623718/java-for-loop-pre-increment-vs-post-increment)

When using the standard `for` loop, how does the compiler treat the incrementing of the for loop variables?

For example,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
            System.out.println("i is : " + i);           
       }
```

Would print out the following

```
i is : 0
i is : 1
i is : 2
i is : 3
i is : 4
```

However, if I alter the incremting to prefix incrementing, the output is the same

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
       {
            System.out.println("i is : " + i);           
       }
```

Does the compiler process the loop in sequential order? such as : `for(initialisation; condition; incrementing)`. Therefore, the incrementing part would only happen after the initialisation and conditions, meaning a prefix or postfix incrementing operator behave the same way?

Bit of a nonsense question, but I'm curious as to how the compiler treats loops