# What's the difference between --i and i--?

Tags: java

In some code i've seen a for loop with a --i as third parameters

```
for(int i=array.length; i<0; --i)
```

Maybe someone can explain me the difference with i-- ?

i guess it's something like the moment when i is decremented ?

Comment: There is no difference in your case.

Comment: Let me google that for you: "What's the difference between ++i and i++"

Comment: `--i` is pre-decrement and `i--` is post-decrement. Goolge/Bing these keywords and you will see ton of articles explaining the differences, but as @Pigueiras said, your example has no difference.

Comment: [java for loop pre-increment vs post-increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623718/java-for-loop-pre-increment-vs-post-increment) covers this well also

Comment: also duplicate of [what is the difference between i++ & ++i in for loop (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2315705/995714)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If, for example, `i = 5`:

`--i` decrements i by 1 then gives you the value of i **(4).**

`i--` gives you the value of i **(5)** then decrements it by 1.

**Both will give you the same result in a for loop.**