# Which is Faster i++ or ++i and why

Tags: java

I'm writing the code for a loop sequence and two codes perform the same function but I want to choose the faster one and to know how to identify which one runs faster

`for (i=0; i<100; i++)` and `for (i=0; i<100; ++i)`

I've used the two codes and they both perform the same function but I do not not know which is faster

Comment: Time to benchmark?

Comment: They perform the same tasks with different order and return value

Comment: considering the evaluated value of i++ or ++i isn't being used, the compiler is supposed to see both as exactly the same. Also, as is said in an answer, don't try to optimize that kind of stuff. Only try to optimize what you profiled as a bottleneck worthy of optimization.

Comment: You can find answers to your question here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831748/is-i-really-faster-than-i-in-for-loops-in-java
In Java, no difference in speed. In C++, ++i is faster under some circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't matter. Also: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/