# Incrementing index in foreach

Tags: php, loops

Why do I get a different output with `$key++` and `$key+1`?

What should I do to refer to the next element in the loop using `foreach`?

```
foreach($diff as $key=>$val) {

if(in_array($diff[$key],$common) && in_array($diff[$key+1],$common)) {}

if(in_array($diff[$key],$common) && in_array($diff[$key++],$common)) {}

}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400518/pre-incrementation-vs-post-incrementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$x++` returns the old value of `$x` (before the increment).  For example, `$x=3; print $x++;` will print "3".  **It also modifies `$x`**, so it's not the best choice unless that's your intent.  (Here, incrementing would be pretty useless, particularly since the modified keys never see the outside of the loop.)

`++$x` would return the new value of `$x`.  Like `$x++`, though, it's semantically wrong for just getting the next number, as it modifies `$x`.

Just stick with `$x + 1`.

Answer (score 4):

- `$key + 1` returns `$key + 1` and does not modify `$key` (see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.arithmetic.php)).
- `$key++` returns `$key` and changes `$key` to `$key + 1` (see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.increment.php)).

You should be using the former as there is no reason to modify `$key`.

Comment: yeah, the arithmetic operator will be useful when looping array with a numeric index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$key+1
```

Always just adds 1 to the `$key` for that instance. It does not modify `$key` at all

```
$key++
```

Increments the `$key` value, and it retains that value when the next loop starts

Answer (score 0):

`$key++` increments the value of `$key` by 1.

`$key+1` adds 1 to the value of `$key`, but does not change it.

Answer (score 0):

`$key + 1` will add on to the key but actually increment `$key`.

`$key++` will take the value of `$key` and after its been returned, then increment $key (after use).