# Read file and store into a variable

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

$userName = array();
$tutorial = array();
$myFile = "students.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile,'r');
while( !feof($myFile) ){
    $userName[] = array(fgets($fh));//Save first line content
    $tutorial[] = array(fgets($fh));//Save second line content
}
fclose($myFile);
echo "$userName";
echo "$tutorial";
?>
```

and my students.txt content

```
dasdsa
A
asdasd
D
```

How to read that and store into different array and print them out

Comment: What output you getting using above method ? Also `$username` is array, us `print_r($userName);` to check output & not echo.

Answer (score 1):

your code should work as expected. I assume you're bit confused with `echo "$userName";` output as it displays Array word. try `var_dump($userName)` instead

Comment: my php keep loading and after that just come with blank page

Comment: what is the size of txt file?

Comment: 1kb only.. it's small text file

Comment: didn't you try to execute it in command shell like 'php myscipt.php'?

Answer (score 0):

Use function [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) in PHP

> file — Reads entire file into an array

```
$array_lines = file('students.txt');
$count =  count($array_lines);

$first_arr = array();
$sec_arr = array();
foreach ($array_lines as $i => $line){
   if($i%2) $first_arr[] = $line;
   else $sec_arr[] = $line;
}

print_r($first_arr);
print_r($sec_arr);
```

With **file()** function every line is read as element in array. You can check it with:

```
print_r($first_arr);
```

Comment: and loop over $array_lines with foreach($array_lines as $line_number=>$line)

Comment: Surely the loop would start at 1 wouldn't it?

Comment: @Robert Because you used `++$i` instead of `$i++` meaning it should add 1 to `$i` FIRST instead of after the iteration. **Edit**: It seems I am wrong - it makes no difference what so ever.

Comment: @h2ooooooo you gotta be joking me :) ++$i is done after loop is finished preincrementation is faster than postincrementation that is why I don't use preincremenation here. Do a simple for loop and try it for yourself. If you don't believe I can create you a fiddle. I don't do `echo $array_lines[++$i]` :)

Comment: @Robert [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400518/pre-incrementation-vs-post-incrementation) surely made it much clearer - I guess I learned something new today (even though, pre-optimization - root of all evil - yatayata).

Comment: i want store into array and not print it . can u guys please see what is my question....

Comment: @h2ooooooo I created fiddle for you http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c5s-66k run this code.

Comment: "*i want store into array and not print it*" "*How to read that and store into different array and **print them out***". Huh?

Comment: @robert. yours 1 only working. but then can u store into more easier way ? just like when i echo the first index of username and first index of tutorial

Comment: so simply put the following code `$array_lines = file('students.txt'); $firstVar = $array_lines[0]; $secondVar = $array_lines[1]; echo $firstVar.$secondVar;`

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as you've done, but change

```
$userName[] = array(fgets($fh));//Save first line content
$tutorial[] = array(fgets($fh));//Save second line content
```

to

```
$userName[] = fgets($fh);//Save first line content
$tutorial[] = fgets($fh);//Save second line content
```

(no need to keep the subitems in their own seperate array)

and print them out by either using [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/print_r), or iterate through them:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($userName); $i++) {
    echo $userName[$i] . " - " . $tutorial[$i];
}
```

Comment: @FeliciaTan It sounds like you have a problem somewhere else. What does `print_r($userName)` and `print_r($tutorial)` reveal? Could you post said output in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = file_get_contents('students.txt');
$text = explode("\n",$text);
$output = array();
foreach($text as $line)
{  
    $output[] = $line;
}
```