# Incrementing a string producing unexpected results

Tags: php, increment

I was just playing around with PHP, can someone please explain to me why the code below prints out 5566 instead of 6666?

```
$a = 5;
$b = $a;

echo $a++ . $b++;
echo "\n";
echo $a++ . $b++;
```

Does it echo $a then add 1 to it? Why doesn't it echo the result?

EDIT:
Another simple example for anyone viewing:

```
$a = 5;
$b = $a++;
echo $a++ . $b;
```

Produces `65`

Comment: use pre-increment operator

Comment: 5566 is the expected output here. echo $a++ prints $a first and then increment the value while echo ++$a will increment $a first and then print it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be echoing out

```
 55
 66
```

because when you place `++` after (suffix) then the increment is done after the statment is executed. if you want

```
 66
 66
```

then do

```
$a = 5;
$b = $a;

echo ++$a . ++$b;
echo "\n";
echo $a++ . $b++;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a `POST-INCREMENT OPERATOR` so the value is first being used(i.e. 5) and then incremented so you are getting 5566.

```
echo $a++ . $b++;  // echo 55 and then a becomes 6 , b becomes 6
echo "\n";
echo $a++ . $b++; // echo 66
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your code, IN first echo it returns the `$a` 's value after that it increment similar to $b.

Here is the $a++ explanation:

```
++$a    Pre-increment   Increments $a by one, then returns $a.
$a++    Post-increment  Returns $a, then increments $a by one.
--$a    Pre-decrement   Decrements $a by one, then returns $a.
$a--    Post-decrement  Returns $a, then decrements $a by one.
```

Hope this will be helpful to you to understand.

Check below questions also:

[Pre-incrementation vs. post-incrementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400518/pre-incrementation-vs-post-incrementation) 
[What's the difference between ++$i and $i++ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Because $a++ is post increment it return value and then increment the value.

try:

```
echo ++$a . ++$b;
echo "\n";
echo $a++ . $b++;
```

it's the same as

```
$a++;
$b++;
echo $a . $b;
echo "\n";
echo $a . $b;
$a++
$b++;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do postincrementation firstly the value is returned and then it is incremented by 1 that is why you get such results.

If you do preincremenation firstly value to $a is added then it is returned in that cause you will see 66 and 77

```
echo ++$a . ++$b;
```

will print 66 as you probably expected.

**Notice** pre incremenation/decrementaiton is faster than post that is why if you don't need to display the value firstly before incremenation/decremation use it.

Morover, if you use reference

```
 $a = 5;
 $b = &$a;

 echo $a++ . $b++;
```

It will output 56

and

```
 $a = 5;
 $b = &$a;

 echo ++$a . ++$b;
```

will output 77 :)