# php - some strange behavior from the output?

Tags: php

I was just playing around with PHP when this happened. Look at the commented code.

```
    <?php
     error_reporting(0); //turns of errors and notices (which will be shown otherwise)

     //here we would've gotten a notice saying $_ has no value, which is true. But PHP        automatically gives it the value 0, then we add one to it. ($_++), add $_ and add $_. So it's    1 + 1 + 1 which is two somehow
     echo ($_++ + $_ + $_);
```

So my question is... why does it output 2?

Comment: Try `echo (++$_ + $_ + $_);` and compare the two results and you get your answer.

Comment: What should it have output?  :P  What, in your mind, is the reasonable value of that expression?

Comment: @cHao It's not *that* clear if you don't know the difference between pre/postincrement ;-)

Comment: @UliKöhler: It's not *that* clear **anyway**.  :)  Some languages (like C, from which PHP ends up inheriting a lot of its behavior) don't even specify when the increment actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answer is contained in your code.

`$_` is `0` initially. By `$_++`, you increment `$_`, setting it to one. Therefore, `$_` is `1`, but the value of the postincrement (!) `$_++` is still 0. The value of `++$_` would be 1.

Then, you add two times `$_` (which is `1`), yielding 2 overall.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400518/pre-incrementation-vs-post-incrementation) for a detailed preincrement/postincrement comparison.