# PHP exponentiation operator precedence

Tags: php, operators, operator-precedence

I read the [PHP.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) which states:

> Operator ** has greater precedence than ++.

But when I run this code I get unexpected output:

```
<?php
$a = 2;
echo(++ $a ** 2); 
// output: 9, means: (++$a) ** 2
// expected: 5, means: ++($a ** 2)
```

Can you help me get it clear why that happens? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try to position the pluses after the `$a` - `($a++ ** 2)`. `++$i` is pre-increment whilst `$i++` post-increment.

Comment: Yes, your code works as expected (exponent first, then increment). I wonder why my code does not (at least comparing to what docs say).

Comment: _Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation._

Comment: AbraCadaver that makes sense. I found this post on the matter: https://gist.github.com/nikic/6699370

Comment: `echo($a++ ** 2);` gives me `4` and then `echo($a)` gives me 3. So PHP internally evalutes `($a ** 2)` and returns the result. at a later stage it updates the value of `$a`.

Comment: @DmitriyLezhnev You really should select an answer if any of them have helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `++$a` is a pre-increment, and `$a++` is a post-increment.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400518/pre-incrementation-vs-post-incrementation)

Also,

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions
> are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. PHP does not
> (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is
> evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should
> be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or
> depending on the surrounding code.
>
> From: [PHP Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: `echo($a++ ** 2);` gives me the same value as `echo($a ** 2);` (php 7.1) this seams to be invalid..

Comment: very interesting `echo($a++ ** 2);` gives me `4` but then `echo($a)`  gives me `3`.  So php first does the `($a ** 2)` and returns that result. after that it sets the valid value of `$a` internally

Comment: Well the code isn't setting `$a++` to equal anything, in other words, `$a` doesn't actually change, as in not stored back into it's original value - unless I misunderstood your comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure, that the documentation is wrong here.

> Operator ** has greater precedence than ++.

This statement seems in contradiction with how grouping obeys to operator precedence.

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation.

In fact if we group `**` before `++`, we obtain `++($a ** 2)`, like it is stated in the question. But this expression is not even valid, because the `++` operator can only be used for a variable, but not for an expression.

The fact that `++` is only valid for a variable implies that no operator with two operands can have higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to happening is that the Post/Pre increments are evaluated outside the operation. So the `**` is executed and the result is returned.

- For a post increment the `$a` variable is updated after the operation.
- For a pre increment the `$a` variable is updated before the operation.

So the documentation

> Operator ** has greater precedence than ++.

Seems a little bit strange to me.

After some searching this is also mentioned in the comments: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php#119098

Ow and in the documentation itself.

```
<?php
// POST
$a = 2;
echo($a ** 2);      // 4
echo(PHP_EOL);
echo($a++ ** 2);    // 9
echo(PHP_EOL);
echo($a);           // 3
echo(PHP_EOL);
echo(PHP_EOL);

// PRE
$a = 2;
echo($a ** 2);      // 4
echo(PHP_EOL);
echo(++$a ** 2);    // 4
echo(PHP_EOL);
echo($a);           // 3
echo(PHP_EOL);
echo(PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as my answer? Except mine explains that precedence doesn't actually set the order of evaluation

Comment: No because `echo($a++ ** 2)` we would except the answer `5` not `4`

Comment: So I take out the code I supplied and we have the same answer, and yours doesn't explain that precedence != evaluation, therefore your answer doesn't actually answer the question asked

Comment: Yes, in the link to the stackoverflow answer in your answer you can see the table :) that's the most important part

Comment: Yep haha I was a bit confused by the `4`, but still a question remains when does the `**` operator get precedence over `++` documented on the page linked by OP

Comment: Again, precedence != evaluation - precedence doesn't determine that. You can force evaluation by wrapping it in parenthesis

Answer (score -1):

Spaces, this is why!

`++ $a ** 2` is different from `++$a ** 2`, that is also different from `++$a**2`

Comment: No, that is not why.