# Basic Incrementation

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, increment

i know this is a very basic question BUT.

I understand the concept behind.  n++, ++n, n--, --n.  HOWEVER

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int count = 1;
    for(int i =1;i<=10;++i){

    count = count * i;
    System.out.print(count);
    }
}
```

So it will print: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

My Question is.  Why if i is incremented as ++i isnt i then treated as 2, instead of 1.  Inst the point of ++i, to increment i before it's manipulated by another operation?

Comment: The increment doesn't happen until AFTER the code on the inside of the loop has executed. You initialized to 1.

Comment: Also, that should print 1,2,6,24, etc since you're multiplying.

Comment: Ummm but count never changes..so your just multiplying what i is by 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't changing the pre to the post increment at the iteration part of a for loop make a difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-fo)

Comment: @user1419012 `count = count * i;` will change count and it will keep going up unless you move the `count = 1;` inside the loop to reset it each time.

Answer (score 11):

> Is the point of ++i, to increment i before it's manipulated by another operation?

The difference between `++i` and `i++` only matters when it's used as part of a bigger expression, e.g.

```
int j = ++i; // Increment then use the new value for the assignment
int k = i++; // Increment, but use the old value for the assignment
```

In this case the operation occurs at the end of each iteration of the loop, *on its own*. So your loop is equivalent to:

```
int count = 1;
// Introduce a new scope for i, just like the for loop does
{
    // Declaration and initialization
    int i = 1;
    // Condition
    while (i <= 10) {
        count = count * i;
        System.out.print(count);

        // Now comes the final expression in the for loop "header"
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Now changing `++i` to `i++` at the end there isn't going to make a difference at all - the value of the expression isn't used for anything.

Comment: Ok so to calarify int j = ++i; // Increment, but use the old value for the assignment
int k = i++; // Increment then use the new value for the assignment.....Meanig that j= i+1 but k=j?

Comment: @user1419012: Assuming each statement is separated (rather than considering the two together), `j` will be 1 *less* than `i` after the assigment, but `k` and `i` would have the same value.

Comment: does j have one more than i?  I agree that k will have the same value as i.

Comment: @Palak: If you believe an answer is wrong, please downvote/comment rather than just editing the answer away from the original intention. (In this case yes, you were right for the first part, but it's still appropriate for the original author to fix this rather for an editor to do so. Edits are for clarifications of typos etc, rather than changing the semantics of the post.)

Comment: Okay @Jon Point noted.

Answer (score 3):

The increment isn't called until after the first iteration of the `for` loop.

While it's true that

```
j = i++;
k = ++i;
```

return different results, think of the `++i` in this context as a standalone line called at the end of every `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use i++ which is a post increment. ++i is called a preincrement and the difference is precisely as you have pointed out.

Comment: I believe ++i is actually more efficient for memory when used in such a fashion. The end result is the same, however.

Comment: @user1432824 Are you saying the loop wouldn't work with pre-increment?

Comment: No Dave i know both will work..i was just just wondering what the difference between the two in this case was.  :)

Comment: @user1419012 Different user, mate.

Comment: @SimplyPanda: The compiler will probably optimize out the extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `++i` happens at the end of the loop, it increments and then checks if the new value still meets the termination condition.

Also, won't the output be:

```
count   i  
1   *   1 = 1
1   *   2 = 2  
2   *   3 = 6   
6   *   4 = 24
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop you wrote is same as:

```
i = 1;
while(i<=10) {
  count = count * i;
  System.out.print(count);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

So that's why!

Answer (score 0):

For i = 0 and While i < 1= 10,
print i,
and then pre-increment i. (++i/i++ doesn't make a difference here).

Here try this though:

```
int i=1;  
while(i <= 10)  
  System.out.print(++i);  


i = 1;  
while (i <= 10)  
  System.out.print(i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other answers, the historical reason for preferring `for(int i=1;i<=10;++i)` over `for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)` is that `++i` does not need to store the old value of `i` in an extra variable.  Thus, `++i` is faster than `i++`, though the speed improvement is negligible.  On modern compilers this speed improvement is done as an optimization, so the two pieces yield the same compiler output.  However, since `++i` is always as fast or faster (e.g., on old C++ compilers) than `i++`, many experienced programs always use `++i` within loops.

As other answers have stated, both pieces of code are functionally equivalent (in the case of a for loop).