# Postfix and prefix difference, when using in a for loop in Java

Tags: java, prefix, postfix-operator

My question is how come when we use ++ in a 'for loop' (++ on the right side) it increases. And in this example its on the right side but it does not increase.

```
int a = 1, y;
b = a++; //so "b" will be 1
         // if we do ++a then "b" will be 2
```

Comment: Question isn't clear. Give more explanation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't changing the pre to the post increment at the iteration part of a for loop make a difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-fo)

Comment: Duplicates about a million other questions. Specifically, this answer to the one I noted as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/3511075/21755 pretty much sums it up

Answer (score 3):

It increases in both the for loop and in your example. `a++` increases `a`, but `b` gets the previous value of `a`.

In a for loop you don't assign the return value of `i++` to a different variable, so it doesn't matter if you write `i++` or `++i`.

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

and

```
for (int i=0;i<5;++i)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Will behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the value of `a` increase.  However, with `b = a++;`, the value of a increase **after** its original value has been assigned to `b` but with `b = ++a;` the value of a increase **before** its value is assigned to `b`.

The distinction is not with the value of a beeing increased or not; it is for the value that is assigned to the variable `b`: the original value before the increase of `a` or the new value after its increase.

If there is no assignment of `a` to some other variable, then there is no difference between `a++` and `++a`.

Answer (score 0):

in a++,
the value of a is incremented after the execution on statement i.e while execution of statement the value is not incremented but is incremented AFTER its execution .

in ++a,
the value of a is incremented during the execution of statement i.e while execution we get the incremented value as the result.