# jQuery indexof from the second same character

Tags: jquery, indexof

how to get the second same character and index from that second character ?

string example: hello&4&I am searching the second same character

I know how to get first "&".

```
position = data.indexOf("&");
```

How to get the second "&" position ? When the 4 number is dynamic ?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the nth occurrence of a character in a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744995/finding-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var data = "hello&4&I";
// offset is the one after the first.
var position = data.indexOf("&", data.indexOf("&") + 1);
console.log(position)
// returns 7
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/OyAg/1/edit)

Oh, and also... this is vanilla js. You don't need JQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can take

```
position = data.lastIndexOf("&");
```

Or use a generic function to get the nth position of a string in a string:
[How to get the nth occurrence in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Comment: If in the sentence will be character "&" ? What to do then ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string :)