# Removing a range starting occurrence with specified place

Tags: javascript

I need to define the text area to delete from 4th occurrence of (_) and preserve the extension.

before `12_345_678_900_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg` after `12_345_678_900.jpg`,

before `34_567_890_123_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg`
after `34_567_890_123.jpg`

Is it possible?

Comment: so, basically ... yes!

Comment: is the first part always the same length? if so you could use substring

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: Would you like to help me?

Comment: @Luiz did it work in the end?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to find the [nth occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744995/finding-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript) and then use substring.

```js
var one='12_345_678_900_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg'; // 12_345_678_900.jpg


function nth_occurrence (string, char, nth) {
    var first_index = string.indexOf(char);
    var length_up_to_first_index = first_index + 1;

    if (nth == 1) {
        return first_index;
    } else {
        var string_after_first_occurrence = string.slice(length_up_to_first_index);
        var next_occurrence = nth_occurrence(string_after_first_occurrence, char, nth - 1);

        if (next_occurrence === -1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return length_up_to_first_index + next_occurrence;  
        }
    }
}

console.log(one.substring(0,nth_occurrence(one,'_',4))+one.substring(one.indexOf('.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, split by "_" and then join back the data you want:

```
var str = "12_345_678_900_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg";
str = str.split("_").slice(0,4).join("_") + "."+ str.split(".").slice(-1)
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are great for this sort of scenario:

```
const data1 = '12_345_678_900_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg'
const data2 = '34_567_890_123_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg'
const re = /^([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+).*(.jpg)$/;

var test1 = data1.replace(re, '$1$2');
var test2 = data2.replace(re, '$1$2');
```

Try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/648xt3qq/

There are probably a few different regular expression approaches that would get the job done

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```js
function clean() {
    var el = document.getElementById('area');
    el.value = el.value.replace(/^(.*?_.*?_.*?_.*?)(_.*?)(\..*?.*)$/gmi, '$1$3');
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" id="area">12_345_678_900_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg
34_567_890_123_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg</textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="clean(); return false;" />
</form>
```