# How to get all but last section of known ip address

Tags: javascript, ip

I am trying to write javascript code that would trim the last section of an ip address (string), such as `123.456.789.012`, and return the trimmed ip string, which in the case of the example would be `123.456.789`

How would this be done (regex?)?

Please excuse my lack of proper terminology. I hope this makes enough sense.

Thanks

Comment: `123.456.789.012` isn't a valid IP address ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Array#slice` could be used over `String#split` and then `Array#join`

```js
var splitted = '123.456.789.012'.split('.');
var op = splitted.slice(0, splitted.length - 1).join('.');
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find the 3rd occurrence of a period in your IP string and then take the substring up to that index. [Finding the nth occurrence of a character in a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744995/finding-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    var a = "123.456.789.012"; 
    var result = a.substr(0,((a.length - a.indexOf(".")) - 1));
    console.log(result);
```