# Why 2 and -2 instead of 1 and -1?

Tags: c++, increment, decrement

I wrote this very simple program:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    cout << x++<<endl;
    cout<<++x<<endl;
    int y = 0;

    cout<<y--<<endl;
    cout<<--y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this is what i got when i ran it:

```
0

2

0

-2
```

i use code::blocks for writing the program and my operating system is Ubuntu 12.10.
how should i fix my program so i will see 0 1 0 -1 instead?

Comment: This ones must have been asked a million times.

Comment: what have you tried?  watch a kazillion answers show up ... and this is a dup's dup's dup!

Comment: Nothing is wrong, except that you invoke side effects you do not understand. Don't use the ++ and -- operator until you do.

Comment: i don't see how i could search to find an exact answer for what i was looking for.

Comment: @dandan78: If it has do you have a reference so we can link to them. Closing as too localized is wrong (as it could be usefull to a lot of people). But if it has been asked before we should link it as a duplicate.

Comment: @loki I didn't vote to close. At any rate, the answers provide sufficient information for anybody who might stumble onto this question.

Comment: @dandan78: But your comment (without any evidence) has inspired others to vote to close (without actually doing it correctly). In the future if you declare its a dup please provide a reference to stop idiots impulse voting to close.

Comment: i agree that my question should have been closed, but because of so many downvotes, now they banned my account..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the [concepts of post increment(decrement) and pre increment(decrement)](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/506780-difference-between-pre-increment-post-increment).

#### Post increment

```
cout << x++<<endl;
```

You can understand this line as "Return the value of x" + "increment the value of x". I.e The return value is before the increment.

So return 0 and increase the value of x to 1.

#### Pre increment

```
cout<<++x<<endl;
```

This is the opposite - the incremented value is returned.

So increase the value of x to 2 and return 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << x++ << endl;
```

Post-increment increments `x` from 0 to 1, and yields the *old* value, 0. The value of `x`is now 1.

```
cout << ++x << endl;
```

Pre-increment increments `x` from 1 to 2, and yields the *new* value, 2. The value of `x`is now 2.

Comment: "Pre-increment increments x from 1 to 2, and yields the new value, 2." why from 1 to 2 when the first value of x is 0? that is what i am looking for.

Comment: @AmirRazoR: The first line increments it to 1, so that is its value before the second line.

Comment: ok now i get it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`x++` will makes your variable 1 but is couted as 0 because of after++ behaviour by that time `++x` will be 2

[Post-increment and pre-increment within a 'for' loop produce same output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

X++ first prints it and then increments the value.
++X first increments the value and then prints it.

so,

```
cout<<x++<<endl   // Prints '0' and increments to '1'
cout<<++x<<endl   // Increments '1' to '2' and prints it
```