# Different between x++ and ++x

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, post-increment, pre-increment

I've known that primary operator (x++) is different form unary operator (++x) when combine with another operator in a statement.

But I wonder whether those two operator is same when leave them alone on the statement. I mean  about compiled code, time to run, ... between:

```
++x;
```

and

```
x++;
```

Which `x` is an integer variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-in-for-loop

Comment: try int `a=++x;` and `a=x++;`, you will see...

Comment: @Thomas: Seem that you've misunderstood me

Comment: Seems you also don't comprehend what is [unary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#C_family_of_languages). Both `x++` and `++x` are unary operations.

Comment: @0x69: Oh, I just got it from MSDN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same in *disassembly* (not IL) on Windows 8 x64:

```
                ++x;
0000004a  inc         dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
                x++;
0000004d  inc         dword ptr [ebp-40h]
```

As you can see, both statements are an `inc` instruction. I used this code to try out:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ++x;
    x++;
}
```