# what is the difference between a++ and ++a or a-- and --a in java?

Tags: java

```
 public void push(E element) {
    if (size == elements.length) {
        resize(); // doubel of size
    }
    elements[size++] = element;
}


public E pop() {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new java.util.EmptyStackException();
    }
    E element = elements[--size];
    elements[size] = null; // set null in last top
    return element;
}
```

what is the difference between a++ and ++a or a-- and --a  in java

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output (Question is asked for C++ but the answer applies to Java as well)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Comment: In this case `--size` reverses what `size++` does.  The important difference is the value left over by the operation.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Postfix Operation**:

`a++` or `a--` is postfix operation, meaning that the value of a will get changed after the evaluation of expression.

```
x = a++;
// This can be rewritten as
x = a;
a = a+1;

// Similarly
y = a--;
// is equivalent to
y = a;
a = a-1;
```

**Prefix Operation**:

`++a` or `--a` is prefix operation, meaning that the value of a will get changed before the evaluation of expression.

```
x = ++a;
// This can be rewritten as
a = a+1;
x = a;

// Similarly
y = --a;
// is equivalent to
a = a-1;
y = a;
```

**Example**:

lets assume this;

```
a = 4;

b = a++; // first b will be 4, and after this a will be 5

// now a value is 5
c = ++a; // first a will be 6, then 6 will be assigned to c
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706225/2260473) also.