# postfix and prefix in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

I came across these examples for sorting, and I'm rather confused about the postfix and prefix here- why it used last-- but ++currIndex here? and in the second example it only used ++pass and ++index? Does these matter in sorting? Many thanks!

```
for (int last = n-1; last >= 1; last--) {
    int largest = indexOfLargest(theArray, last+1);
     int temp = theArray[largest]; 
     swap theArray[largest] = theArray[last]; 
     theArray[last] = temp;
 }

 private static int indexOfLargest(int[] theArray, int size) { 
     int indexSoFar = 0;
     for (int currIndex = 1; currIndex < size; ++currIndex) {
        if (theArray[currIndex]>theArray[indexSoFar])
           indexSoFar = currIndex;
      }
  return indexSoFar;
```

Example 2:

```
for (int pass = 1; (pass < n) && !sorted; ++pass) {
     sorted = true; 
       for (int index = 0; index < n-pass; ++index) {
           int nextIndex = index + 1;
           if (theArray[index]>theArray[nextIndex]) {
               int temp = theArray[index];
               theArray[index] = theArray[nextIndex];
               theArray[nextIndex] = temp;
 }
```

Comment: **In a for loop** (the increment part), using postfix (var++) or prefix (++var) doesn't change anything.

Comment: It does not matter if you use `pass++` or `++pass`.It would matter if you do `a=++pass` and `a=pass++` then you will have different values for `a` for both statements.

Comment: A near-duplicate, for [tag:c] and [tag:c++]: [Post-increment and pre-increment within a 'for' loop produce same output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4706199/2157640)

Answer (score 0):

In simple, it doesn't affect sorting.
It's your logical decision on how you wanted to perform the incrementation/decremental

For example

```
int i = 0;

while (something) {  //any loop for/while
    array[++i] = some data; //increment i first and then next do operation
}

is similar to 

int i = 1;
while (something) {
    array[i++] = some data; //do operation and then increment
}
```

But the important difference is `++i` is executed first and then the operation you wanted to perform based on i. In the other case, it's operation performed on i first and then incrementation

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example ++variable_name and variable_name++ does not make much difference.
In first example,
            they are starting from initial index and that's why used ++currIndex.
In same example in for loop they are starting from last index and to reach first index they have used last-- (or --last in here).

and in second example for both for loops they are starting from first index and that's why using ++pass and ++index.