# What does the ++ sign mean in programming code?

Tags: javascript

What does the ++ sign mean in this code:

```
for (var i=0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    alert(myString[i]);
}

while (x>y) {
    alert ("xrules!");
    y++;
}
```

Comment: Na.. not everyone is going to have the coding vocabulary to search for that post in the same way.

Comment: Did you really just ask for an explanation of Python syntax, using a JS snippet as an example? How does that make any sense whatsoever?

Comment: `++` doesn't mean *anything* in Python.

Comment: @chepner - Well, technically, `++6` means "positive positive six," so that's something... sort of...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Good point. Not an operator, but not completely unparseable.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [increment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) operator.  It's ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output)) equivalent to saying `i = i + 1`

Note that the increment operator does not exist in python, you have to either write the whole thing out or use the add assignment operator `i += 1`

Note that there are post (`i++`) and pre (`++i`) increment operators, as well as equivalent decrement operators `--i` `i--`.  These operators differ on when the increment is applied, and are often a cause of frustration for new programmers.

Comment: thanks ktbiz. so if the increment or decrement operator is before i does it mean the same thing?

Comment: Not quite, hence the frustation.  Here's a [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output) of the differences between the pre and post increment operators.  The same applies for the decrement.

Answer (score 0):

++ is the increment operator

saying

```
y++
```

is the same thing as saying

```
y = y + 1
```