# How to efficiently rotate an array?

Tags: c#, algorithm, memory-efficient

Given an array of `n` integers and a number, `d`, perform  left rotations on the array. Then print the updated array as a single line of space-separated integers.

**Sample Input:**

> 5 4
>   1 2 3 4 5

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of `n` (the number of integers) and `d` (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
The second line contains `n` space-separated integers describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

**Sample Output:**

> 5 1 2 3 4

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    string[] arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int n = Int32.Parse(arr_temp[0]);
    int d = Int32.Parse(arr_temp[1]);

    string[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    string[] ans = new string[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ans[(i + n - d) % n] = arr[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        Console.Write(ans[j] + " ");
    }
}
```

How to use less memory to solve this problem?

Comment: @FirstStep post and pre increment only really make a difference when assigning the result.

Comment: @juharr I thought "_Given that i++ needs to remember the old value of i after incrementing, I think ++i may be shorter_" From reading comments in [**Post-increment and pre-increment within a 'for' loop produce same output**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output)

Comment: Sounds like a CodinGame contest ;-)

Comment: public static int[] ArrayRotateLeftWithSmallTempArray(int[] a, int s)
        {
            var l = a.Length;
            var t = new int[s]; // temp array with size s = shift

            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
                // save cells which will be replaced 
                if (i < s)
                    t[i] = a[i];

                if (i + s < l)
                    a[i] = a[i + s];
                else
                    a[i] = t[i + s - l];
            }

            return a;
        }

     https://github.com/sam-klok/ArraysRotation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will use less memory in most cases as the second array is only as big as the shift.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] n = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    LeftShiftArray(n, 4);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", n));
}

public static void LeftShiftArray<T>(T[] arr, int shift)
{
    shift = shift % arr.Length;
    T[] buffer = new T[shift];
    Array.Copy(arr, buffer, shift);
    Array.Copy(arr, shift, arr, 0, arr.Length - shift);
    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, arr, arr.Length - shift, shift);
}
```

Comment: Maybe we can solve this problem without using `arr `?

Comment: Well, you can do LeftShiftArray(n, 1); the times you need. You dont need extra memory but a lot of I/O operations are needed.

Comment: @lorentz-vedeler Hmm, it worked and seems it was pretty fast. I wonder why my approach with using temporary cell for storing first element timed out on big chunks of data... I also copied the rest of cells like a[i] = a[i + 1]...

Comment: @Alexander: that could probably warrant its own question on codereview or stackoverflow, but in short: 1. your algorithm is O(kn) where k is the number of shifted elements and n is the length of the array. 2. Array.Copy is significantly faster than copying elements manually. 3. There's a lot of branching logic inside your loops.

Comment: I would suggest returning `buffer` (or e new better name) from `LeftShiftArray` and writing `n=LeftShiftArray(...)`, so you can use one less `Copy`. The allocation is done anyway and replacing a reference is cheaper than a copy.

Answer (score 9):

Do you really need to physically move anything? If not, you could just shift the index instead.

For example, if the array arr of size n were shifted to the left 3 places then we'd store shift=3. Then, when asked to access the shifted arr at index i, we instead access the unshifted arr at index (i + shift) % n.

This behaves identically to a shifted array, but because we're applying shifts to the index rather than physically shifting every cell of the array, it takes constant O(1) time instead of linear O(n).

Comment: This is an underrated answer!  Maybe it isn't a good fit for solving this homework problem, but in production it is great! (Also similar answers to a number of other problems ...)

Answer (score 8):

This problem can get a bit tricky but also has a simple solution if one is familiar with Queues and Stacks.
All I have to do is define a Queue (which will contain the given array) and a Stack.
Next, I just have to Push the Dequeued index to the stack and Enqueue the Popped index in the Queue and finally return the Queue.
Sounds confusing? Check the code below:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {

    Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>(a);
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

    while(d > 0)
    {
        stack.Push(queue.Dequeue());
        queue.Enqueue(stack.Pop());
        d--;            
    }

    return queue.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: why don't just use queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue()); ?

Comment: It's a neat trick but worth mentioning that this triples the memory requirements.

Comment: The user did specifically mention that they looking for a solution with less memory usage.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you asked 2 questions:

> How to **efficiently** rotate an array?

and

> How to **use less memory** to solve this problem?

Usually efficiency and low memory usage are mutually exclusive. So I'm going to answer your second question, still providing the most efficient implementation under that memory constraint.

The following method can be used for both left (passing negative count) or right (passing positive count) rotation. It uses **O(1)** space (single element) and **O(n * min(d, n - d))** array element copy operations (**O(min(d, n - d))** array block copy operations). In the worst case scenario it performs **O(n / 2)** block copy operations.

The algorithm is utilizing the fact that

> rotate_left(n, d) == rotate_right(n, n - d)

Here it is:

```
public static class Algorithms
{
    public static void Rotate<T>(this T[] array, int count)
    {
        if (array == null || array.Length < 2) return;
        count %= array.Length;
        if (count == 0) return;
        int left = count < 0 ? -count : array.Length + count;
        int right = count > 0 ? count : array.Length - count;
        if (left <= right)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < left; i++)
            {
                var temp = array[0];
                Array.Copy(array, 1, array, 0, array.Length - 1);
                array[array.Length - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < right; i++)
            {
                var temp = array[array.Length - 1];
                Array.Copy(array, 0, array, 1, array.Length - 1);
                array[0] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage like in your example:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToArray(); // { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } 
array.Rotate(-4); // { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't using IEnumerables better? Since It won't perform all of those maths, won't allocate that many arrays, etc

```
public static int[] Rotate(int[] elements, int numberOfRotations)
{
    IEnumerable<int> newEnd = elements.Take(numberOfRotations);
    IEnumerable<int> newBegin = elements.Skip(numberOfRotations);
    return newBegin.Union(newEnd).ToArray();
}
```

IF you don't actually need to return an array, you can even remove the .ToArray() and return an IEnumerable

Usage:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] n = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int d = 4;
    int[] rotated = Rotate(n,d);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", rotated));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried this and below is my approach... 
Thank you

```
public static int[] RotationOfArray(int[] A, int k)
  {
      if (A == null || A.Length==0)
          return null;
      int[] result =new int[A.Length];
      int arrayLength=A.Length;
      int moveBy = k % arrayLength;
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
      {
          int tmp = i + moveBy;
          if (tmp > arrayLength-1)
          {
              tmp =  + (tmp - arrayLength);
          }
          result[tmp] = A[i];             
      }        
      return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to used stack and queue in C# to achieve the output as follows:

```
public int[] rotateArray(int[] A, int rotate)
{
    Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>(A);
    Stack<int> s;
    while (rotate > 0)
    {
        s = new Stack<int>(q);
        int x = s.Pop();
        s = new Stack<int>(s);
        s.Push(x);
        q = new Queue<int>(s);
        rotate--;
    }
    return q.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solve the challange from Hackerrank by following code. Hope it helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class ArrayLeftRotationSolver
{
    TextWriter mTextWriter;
    public ArrayLeftRotationSolver()
    {
         mTextWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

    }

    public void Solve()
    {

        string[] nd = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(nd[0]);

        int d = Convert.ToInt32(nd[1]);

        int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp))
        ;
        int[] result = rotLeft(a, d);

        mTextWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));

        mTextWriter.Flush();
        mTextWriter.Close();
    }

    private int[] rotLeft(int[] arr, int shift)
    {
        int n = arr.Length;
        shift %= n;
        int[] vec = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            vec[(n + i - shift) % n] = arr[i];
        }
        return vec;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ArrayLeftRotationSolver solver = new ArrayLeftRotationSolver();
         solver.Solve();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Comment: That is the same code as the question, with the same problem - it requires double the space of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
public static int[] leftrotation(int[] arr, int d)
    {

        int[] newarr = new int[arr.Length];
        var n = arr.Length;
        bool isswapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int index = Math.Abs((i) -d);
            if(index == 0)
            {
                isswapped = true;
            }

            if (!isswapped)
            {
                int finalindex = (n) - index;
                newarr[finalindex] = arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                newarr[index] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return newarr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the Item at position 0 and add it at the end. remove the item at position 0. repeat n times.

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>(); 

    private void shift(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            iList.Add(iList[0]);
            iList.RemoveAt(0);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I thought I'd add another possible solution using just one intermediate array (really, 2 if you include the LINQ Take expression).  This code rotates to right rather than left, but may be useful nonetheless.

```
public static Int32[] ArrayRightRotation(Int32[] A, Int32 k)
    {
        if (A == null)
        {
            return A;
        }

        if (!A.Any())
        {
            return A;
        }

        if (k % A.Length == 0)
        {
            return A;
        }

        if (A.Length == 1)
        {
            return A;
        }

        if (A.Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {
            return A;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            var intermediateArray = new List<Int32> {A.Last()};
            intermediateArray.AddRange(A.Take(A.Length - 1).ToList());
            A = intermediateArray.ToArray();
        }

        return A;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**O(1) space, O(n) time solution**

I think in theory this is as optimal as it gets, since it makes a.Length in-place swaps and 1 temp variable swap per inner loop.

However I suspect O(d) space solutions would be faster in real life due to less code branching (fewer CPU command pipeline resets) and cache locality (mostly sequential access vs in d element steps).

```
static int[] RotateInplaceLeft(int[] a, int d)
{
    var swapCount = 0;

    //get canonical/actual d    
    d = d % a.Length;
    if(d < 0) d += a.Length;
    if(d == 0) return a;

    for (var i = 0; swapCount < a.Length; i++) //we're done after a.Length swaps
    {
        var dstIdx = i; //we need this becasue of ~this: https://youtu.be/lJ3CD9M3nEQ?t=251 
        var first = a[i]; //save first element in this group

        for (var j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
        {
            var srcIdx = (dstIdx + d) % a.Length;
            if(srcIdx == i)// circled around 
            {
                a[dstIdx] = first;
                swapCount++;
                break; //hence we're done with this group
            }
            a[dstIdx] = a[srcIdx];
            dstIdx = srcIdx;
            swapCount++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: YOu could improve this by replacing `break` with `else` and moving the common `++swapCount` to after the `if`. Then you could also change the `for` to `for (int i = 0, swapCount = 0;` and make it `void` since it modifies `a` in place. Finally you could make it generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at constrains you will see that d <= n (number of rotations <= number of elements in array). Because of that this can be solved in 1 line.

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d)
{
    return a.Skip(d).Concat(a.Take(d)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // using the same same array, and only one temp variable
    // shifting everything several times by one
    // works, simple, but slow
    public static int[] ArrayRotateLeftCyclical(int[] a, int shift)
    {
        var length = a.Length;

        for (int j = 0; j < shift; j++)
        {
            int t = a[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (i == length - 1)
                    a[i] = t;
                else
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an in-place `Rotate` implementation of [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74720719/rotate-array-of-k-position-performance-c-sharp/74725383#74725383) posted by [גלעד ברקן](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034787) in another question. The trick is:

> Example, k = 3:
>
> ```
> 1234567
> ```
>
> First reverse in place each of the two sections delineated by n-k:
>
> ```
> 4321 765
> ```
>
> Now reverse the whole array:
>
> ```
> 5671234
> ```

My implementation, based on the [`Array.Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse) method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Rotate left for negative k. Rotate right for positive k.
/// </summary>
public static void Rotate<T>(T[] array, int k)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(array);
    k = k % array.Length;
    if (k < 0) k += array.Length;
    if (k == 0) return;
    Debug.Assert(k > 0);
    Debug.Assert(k < array.Length);

    Array.Reverse(array, 0, array.Length - k);
    Array.Reverse(array, array.Length - k, k);
    Array.Reverse(array);
}
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GuuJkx).

Output:

```
Array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
Rotate(5)
Array: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
Rotate(-2)
Array: 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if I have a array of integer 'Arr'. To rotate the array 'n' you can do as follows:

```
static int[] leftRotation(int[] Arr, int n)
{
    int tempVariable = 0;
    Queue<int> TempQueue = new Queue<int>(a);
      for(int i=1;i<=d;i++)
       {
           tempVariable = TempQueue.Dequeue();
           TempQueue.Enqueue(t);
    }

    return TempQueue.ToArray();`
}
```

Let me know if any comments. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't compile. There is no a or t defined anywhere. Maybe you should revise your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt. It is easy, but for some reason it timed out on big chunks of data:

```
        int arrayLength = arr.Length;
        int tmpCell = 0;
        for (int rotation = 1; rotation <= d; rotation++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < arrayElementMinValue || arr[i] > arrayElementMaxValue)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Array element needs to be between {arrayElementMinValue} and {arrayElementMaxValue}");
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    tmpCell = arr[0];
                    arr[0] = arr[1];
                }
                else if (i == arrayLength - 1)
                {
                    arr[arrayLength - 1] = tmpCell;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
 public static void RotateArrayAndPrint(int[] n, int rotate)
    {
         for (int i = 1; i <= n.Length; i++)
        {
            var arrIndex = (i + rotate) > n.Length ? n.Length - (i + rotate) : (i + rotate);
            arrIndex = arrIndex < 0 ? arrIndex * -1 : arrIndex;
            var output = n[arrIndex-1];
            Console.Write(output + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very straight forward answer.
Main thing is how you choose the start index.

```
    public static List<int> rotateLeft(int d, List<int> arr) {
        int n = arr.Count;
        List<int> t = new List<int>();
        int h = d;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        { 
            if ((j + d) % n == 0)
            {
                h = 0;
            }
           
            t.Add(arr[h]);
            h++;
        } 

        return t;
    }
```

using this code, I have successfully submitted to hacker rank problem,

Answer (score 0):

```
    // fast and beautiful method
    // reusing the same array
    // using small temp array to store replaced values when unavoidable
    // a - array, s - shift 
    public static int[] ArrayRotateLeftWithSmallTempArray(int[] a, int s)
    {
        var l = a.Length;
        var t = new int[s]; // temp array with size s = shift

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            // save cells which will be replaced by shift
            if (i < s)
                t[i] = a[i];

            if (i + s < l)
                a[i] = a[i + s];
            else
                a[i] = t[i + s - l];
        }

        return a;
    }
```

https://github.com/sam-klok/ArraysRotation

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Rotate(int[] arr, int steps)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            int previousValue = arr[arr.Length - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                int currentValue = arr[j];

                arr[j] = previousValue;
                previousValue = currentValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not so memory efficient but it is easy to read by using Queue:

```
 public void Rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    Queue<int> numbers = new Queue<int>();
    int n = nums.Length;
    k = k%n;
    int start = n - k;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers.Enqueue(nums[(start+i)%n]);
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = numbers.Dequeue();
    }
}
```