# Rotating an array to the left without using shift

Tags: c#, arrays

I was able to get my array to sort to the right but, struggling 
   to get the left  rotation to work for example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` if
   rotated to the left `4` spaces `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3]` I feel like it's *super simple* and just a small change to my current *right rotation* but, I'm stumped.

```
if (direction == "right")
            {
                {
                    //make spaces<nums.Length
                    if (spaces > newArray.Length)
                    {
                        while (spaces - newArray.Length >= 0)
                        {
                            spaces = spaces - newArray.Length;
                        }
                    }

                    if (spaces == 0)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int[] temp = new int[spaces];

                        //move to a temp array
                        for (var i = temp.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            temp[i] = newArray[newArray.Length - spaces + i];
                        }
                        //push to the end
                  for (var j = newArray.Length - spaces - 1; j >= 0; j-   -)
                        {
                            newArray[j + spaces] = newArray[j];
                        }
                        //put the ones in temp array back to the top
                        for (var s = 0; s < temp.Length; s++)
                        {
                            newArray[s] = temp[s];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: As long as you are allocating a utility array anyway, I think it's a lot simpler to just build the new sequence there and replace the original array with the new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently rotate an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482696/how-to-efficiently-rotate-an-array)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214680/hacker-rank-array-left-rotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wel, if you want it *simple*, try *Linq* and *modulo arithmetics*:

```
  int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

  int shift = 4;

  int[] result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, array.Length)
    .Select(i => array[(i + shift % array.Length + array.Length) % array.Length])
    .ToArray();
```

Same *modulo arithmetics* and no *Linq*

```
  int shift = 4;

  int[] result = new int[array.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i)  
    result[i] = array[(i + shift % array.Length + array.Length) % array.Length];
```

If you want to rotate to *right*, assign *negative* values to `shift`.

**Edit:** what's going under the hood, *modulo arithmetics* explained. Our task is when we are given `i` (index of `result`) to compute `index` of the initial `array`:

```
 array  = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
 result = {5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4}
```

as we can see,

```
 index = i + shift
```

when `shift` is *small enough* (`5` is taken from `0 + 4 == 4`th index). However we can't exceed `array`s length but should subtract it (i.e. restart from `0`)

```
 7 + 4 == 11 -> 11 - 8 == 3
```

I.e.

```
 index = i + shift

 index >= array.Length 
   ? index - array.Length // index is too large, restart from 0
   : index;               // index is small enough
```

This operation is equal to *remainder* `%`:

```
 index = (i + shift) % array.Length
```

It's *good enough*, but we still have **2** *specific issues* with **.Net**:

1. `i + shift` can result in *integer oveflow* (when, say `shift = int.MaxValue`)
2. .Net can well return *negative* remainder (if `shift < 0`)

That's why `shift % array.Length` to meet the first issue and `+ array.Length` for the second. Finally

```
(i + shift % array.Length + array.Length) % array.Length
```

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote twice for the *non-linq* version. However, if you can explain how the modulo arithmetics work, for this case, this answer will be perfect

Comment: Well the issue here is I'm not allowed to do it the easy way that's why its so drawn out.

Comment: I cant use the shift op unfortunately

Comment: @Zdad91 There's no shift op used. It's just a variable name.

Comment: You wouldn't want to use the shift op anyway. It makes no sense in this context. It's for shifting bits, not array elements.

Comment: @Zdad91 if this answers your question, you can tick the check mark, below the score of this answer (top left of that answer). This is rewarding for you and the one who answers your question (both earn reputation) and this will tells the future readers that they can use this answer if they have the same question than you

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public void Rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    int[] rotated = new int[nums.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) {
        int rem = (i + k) % nums.Length;
        rotated[rem] = nums[i];
    }
    Array.Copy(rotated, nums, rotated.Length);
   }

}

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
Explanation:
rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]
rotate 2 steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]
rotate 3 steps to the right: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```