# C# I have to rotate this array to the right but Im not sure how to do it

Tags: c#, arrays

I have to rotate the array I imputed n number of places(I also select that) and I did that... but I have messed something up and Im not sure how to fix it. If you have seen some of this code online, sorry im not that good at it so I use google to help myself.

The results should be like this:

-input:
15 5 8 19 9 10

n:4

-output:
8 19 9 10 15 5

-input:
11 4 12 17 18 7 8 16

n:2

-output:
8 16 11 4 12 17 18 7

```
    public static class Homework
    {





        static void RightRotate(int[] arr, int d,int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
                RightRotatebyOne(arr, n);

        }

        static void RightRotatebyOne(int[] arr, int n)
        {
            int i, temp = arr[0];
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

            arr[i] = temp;
        }


        static void printArray(int[] arr, int size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
        }





        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            int a = arr.Length;
            int n =  Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            RightRotate(arr, n, a);
            printArray(arr, a);

        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I dont know if its the same or not. I just dont know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently rotate an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482696/how-to-efficiently-rotate-an-array)

Comment: I think you're rotating left instead of right. the logic in RightRotatebyOne is reversed. Also, suggest you use better names for variables so it would be more readable