# Elegant way to rotate items inside of array or list in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, take

This is a general array question but, for my case, it is a list of strings.

Given: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] and an item inside of the collection, say f.

Output: [f, g, h, a, b, c, d, e]

I can use substring methods or things like .take and .skip. But are there any cleaner alternatives like using linq or something else I might be unaware of?

edit: Okay, I apologize that I did not write question correctly. When I say LINQ, I meant something involving lambda expressions? Thanks for your comments. I will just stick with take and skip.

Comment: `.Take()` and `.Skip()` *are* Linq.

Comment: not really clear what you want to do, your example have nothing to do with substring, you present 'Output' without saying what rules led to that output.

Comment: I think you're doing two things. 1) get the index of an item, 2) [rotate a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948202/easiest-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @gunr2171 THANK YOU! "Rotating" was the term I was looking for.

Comment: LINQ is for querying data and creating new collections - since you are using `Take` and `Skip` I assume creating a new `List` to replace the existing list is okay with you?

Answer (score 2):

The `Take()` and `Skip()` methods are part of the LINQ. I do not see how you could rearrange the items inside the list via LINQ without using these methods.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
string character = "f";
int i = list.IndexOf(character);

if (i != -1)
{
  list = list.Skip(i).Concat(list.Take(i)).ToList();
}
```

You could also use `List` specific methods like below

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
string character = "f";
int i = list.IndexOf(character);

if (i != -1)
{
   var sublist = list.GetRange(i, list.Count - i);
   list.RemoveRange(i, list.Count - i);
   list.InsertRange(0, sublist);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating a new `List` or array, you can use an extension method (for `IEnumerable<T>`) to rotate the items and then create the collection you want.

```
// num - return items starting with numth item and wrapping around
//       e.g. rotate items so that numth item is first
public static IEnumerable<T> Rotate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int num) {
    if (num > 0)
        if (items is IList<T> itemList) {
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < itemList.Count; ++j1)
                yield return itemList[(j1+num) % itemList.Count];
        }
        else
            using (var itemsEnum = items.GetEnumerator()) {
                var q = new Queue<T>();

                while (itemsEnum.MoveNext() && num-- > 0)
                    q.Enqueue(itemsEnum.Current);

                do {
                    yield return itemsEnum.Current;
                } while (itemsEnum.MoveNext());

                while (q.Count > 0)
                    yield return q.Dequeue();
            }
}
```

With this extension method, you can do

```
var ans = src.Rotate(src.IndexOf("f")).ToList(); // or .ToArray()
```

If you want to do this with no additional object creation, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58977280/2557128) instead.

Answer (score 0):

another possibility

```
var newlist = new List<string>(oldList.Count);
newList.Add("f");
newList.AddRange(oldList.Where(x=>x!="f"));
```

less efficeint since it keeps looking at the elements even after its found the target one, but the code is simple