# Rotate array of k position performance c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, for-loop

I'm solving problems on LeetCode, and referring to this problem: [189. Rotate Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/description/?envType=study-plan&id=algorithm-i)

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
> Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
> ```

I gave my solution as:

```
public void Rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    if (k <= 0)
        return;

    int t = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        t = nums[nums.Length - 1];

        for (int j = nums.Length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
        }

        nums[0] = t;
    }
}
```

My question is not about the solution, but is about its *performance*.

Can I improve my solution to *be faster*? Or is wrong my approach?

Cause it pass all the test cases, but it *fail* the last one cause is a *big array with big numbers*, and it fail on being *fast enough*, it gives me

> "Time Limit Exceeded"

Comment: Related: [How to efficiently rotate an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482696/how-to-efficiently-rotate-an-array)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko please don't recreate tags that have [previously been removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399117/6296561). The [leetcode] tag is not a good tag for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine: OK, I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for *performance* you can get rid of *nested loops* to have `O(n)` time complexity vs. `O(n * n)`:

1. Compute what each item of the `result` array should be
2. Copy `result` array into initial one

Code:

```
public void Rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.Length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i) {
        int index = (i + k % nums.Length + nums.Length) % nums.Length;
        
        result[index] = nums[i];
    }
    
    Array.Copy(result, nums, nums.Length);
}
```

Note, that in general case we have a quite complex formula for `index`:

```
  int index = (i + k % nums.Length + nums.Length) % nums.Length;
```

we should be ready for *negative* `k` (while `index` must not be negative) and *huge* `k` (possible integer overflow). If `k >= 0` and `k <= 1e5` as Leet Code claims we can simplify `index` into

```
  int index = (i + k) % nums.Length;
```

and have compact solution as

```
public void Rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.Length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i) 
        result[(i + k) % nums.Length] = nums[i];
    
    Array.Copy(result, nums, nums.Length);
}
```

**Edit:** Why `%` (remainder) appears in `index` formula?

Let's have a look on what's going on. When `i + k` is less than `nums.Length` we should write the value just at `i + k` index. When `i + k == nums.Length` we should write at `index == 0`, when `i + k == nums.Length + 1` we should write at `index == 1`, ..., when `i + k == nums.Length + r` then we should write at `index == r`, note that `r == (i + k) % nums.Length == (nums.Length + r) % nums.Length == 0 + r == r`

Comment: Can you explain how are you using % to get the index please?

Comment: Thank you, I tried to modify your solution to don't use extra space but I couldn't find a way to make it easy. And I like the use of the % to skip a lot of operations. And i guess that to make mine faster the only way was to remove a loop

Answer (score 2):

You could run it in a single while loop. I don't have leetcode so I can't test it, I just ran it locally but if you run this what do you get? Also, it doesn't do the in place movement so if there is a memory test it might fail that.

```
  public static int[] Rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
        if (k <= 0) return nums;
        var n = new int[nums.Length];
        var stopAt = nums.Length - k;
        while(stopAt < 0) {
            stopAt = nums.Length - Math.Abs(stopAt);
        }
        var i = stopAt;
        var y = 0;
        while (true) {
            n[y] = nums[i];
            y++;
            i++;
            if (i >= nums.Length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (i == stopAt) break;
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: often `k < 0` means that we should rotate to the *opposite* side.

Comment: `Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.` Is why I didn't account for negatives. And yeah, I should have checked for `IndexOutOfBounds` but I was just throwing a quick solution together.

Comment: Updated my answer to deal with `k > nums.length`. I'm sure there's a more elegant solution but I'm no maths whiz.

Comment: It's correct now, all leet code tests are passed.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for checking and helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick to performing this in place that involves a transformation over two steps. O(n) time, O(1) space.

Example, k = 3:

```
1234567
```

First reverse in place each of the two sections delineated by n-k:

```
4321 765
```

Now revese the whole array:

```
5671234
```

Reversing sections in place left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Very clever! I posted an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74725759/11178549).