# why my code is giving undeclared variable error?

Tags: c++

```
   include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>



    std::vector<int> biggest;

std::vector<int>vector1;
std::vector<int>vector2;


int main(){
biggest = [vector2[0],0]; //wrong initialization
for (int apply = 0; apply < (vector2.size()); apply++) {
    if (biggest[0] < vector2[apply + 1]) {
        biggest[0] = vector2[apply + 1];
        biggest[1] = apply + 1;
    }

}
```

Error   C2065   'apply': undeclared identifier.why this error is occurring as i have already defined apply variable in for loop. error should be in initialization of biggest(vector).why wrong compiler code?
even intellisense is not giving me error is it a visual studio bug?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: My crystal ball say you are using `apply` after that loop.

Comment: In a for loop, try using `++apply` instead of `apply++`

Comment: @KorbenDose There is no difference between the two here.

Comment: no, error comes in these lines

Comment: @karanshaarma post a [mcve] as the code above does not reproduce the error.

Comment: @interjay You are right, here is no difference. Might still be a [good idea to get into the habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output).

Comment: For the same reason we are complaining. Cause both we and the compiler see a  name(s) without a matching declaration(s). So we haven't a clue.

Comment: yeah i know but these line don't compile.i don't know why? .i am using visual studio 17 community edition. is it's IDE fault?

Comment: @karanshaarma: No it's not the IDE or the compiler.

Comment: sorry guys, i have found the solution i was initializing biggest array in wrong way but don't know  why i was getting this kind of error.

Comment: At this point you should either delete the question or show a minimal example to reproduce whatever problem you had that was causing this error. Not showing a minimal example is the reason why you have downvotes on this question.

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is in scope in the `for` loop body, so be assured, the error is not there. But you are aware that `apply` is out of scope *after* the loop body?

I'm only answering this because your use of

```
vector2.size() - 1
```

**will give you hell** if `vector2` is empty, as the above will wrap around to a large `unsigned` value and your program will fail spectacularly! Use

```
for (int apply=0; apply + 1 < vector2.size(); apply++) {
```

instead.

Comment: i have changed it but still error. let me see if i can upload a snapshot of it

Comment: @karanshaarma: no, don't upload a snapshot, upload a cut down version of the code that exhibits the error.

Comment: sorry guys, i have found the solution i was initializing biggest array in wrong way but don't know  why i was getting this kind of error.