# What is the difference between i++ and ++i?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between myInt++ and ++myInt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437026/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-myint-and-myint)

**Duplicate:** [In C# what is the difference between myInt++ and ++myInt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437026/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-myint-and-myint)

In .NET, please.

**Update**: can anyone post a sample scenario of which to use, because both looks very similar to me.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437026/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-myint-and-myint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `i++` is a post-increment, meaning this expression returns the original value of i, then increments it.
- `++i` is a pre-increment, meaning this expression increments i, and returns the new value

Many languages aside from C# support this expression behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine(++i); // prints 1
Console.WriteLine(i++); // prints 1 also
Console.WriteLine(i); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Check out this example below..

```
int a = 0;
int i = 5;

//Value of a: 0, i: 5

a=i++;

//Value of a: 5, i: 6

a=++i;

//Value of a: 7, i: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

to make it a bit clearer:

```
i = 0

print i++  // prints 0 and increases i AFTERWARDS
print i    // prints "1"

i = 0 

print ++i  // increases i FIRST, and then prints it ( "1" )
print i    // prints "1"
```

As you can see the difference is WHEN the value of the variable is updated, before or after its read and used in the current statement